# How do I implement onchange of <input type="text"> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, input, onchange

`<select>` has this API. What about `<input>`?

Answer (score 249, accepted):

You can use [`.change()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/change)

```
$('input[name=myInput]').change(function() { ... });
```

However, this event will only fire when the selector has lost focus, so you will need to click somewhere else to have this work.

If that's not quite right for you, you could use some of the other [jQuery events](http://docs.jquery.com/Events) like [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/), [keydown](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) or [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) - depending on the exact effect you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for a hidden input. A possible solution when required a onchange on a hidden input is: <input type='text' style='display:none' /> (with css)..

Comment: Note that `change` will only fire when the input element has lost focus. There is also the `input` event which fires whenever the textbox updates without it needing to lose focus. Unlike key events it also works for pasting/dragging text.

Comment: Great comment @pimvdb.  I used this, and turned it into an answer to this question.

Comment: As I am trying this, and have just learned that the event only fires when two conditions are met: 1) value change; and 2) blur, I wonder if what many people expect of change() is better handled by keyup() ?

Comment: As `change` isn't supported by IE9, you can use `focusout` to have the same comportment

Comment: The note on losing focus is what helped me .. . .

Answer (score 285):

As @pimvdb said in his comment,

> Note that change will only fire when the input element has lost focus.
>   There is also the input event which fires whenever the textbox updates
>   without it needing to lose focus. Unlike key events it also works for
>   pasting/dragging text.

(See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.oninput).)

This is so useful, it is worth putting it in an answer.  Currently (v1.8*?) there is no .input() convenience fn in jquery, so the way to do it is

```
$('input.myTextInput').on('input',function(e){
 alert('Changed!')
});
```

Comment: Particularly, IE<9 does not support at all.

Comment: Since you can bind to multiple events `$('form').on('change input', function);` did the trick for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Norris.  That will probably fire twice when an element is changed (1st), and loses focus (2nd).  That is not a problem for many purposes, but is worth noting nevertheless.

Comment: Tested at IE9, backspace will not be fired

Comment: Note, this will fire for every input change made (which might be what you're looking for). But, if you're looking for an event like "When done changing", [here's a great example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4220182/5667951).

Answer (score 89):

I would suggest using the keyup event something like below:

```
$('elementName').keyup(function() {
 alert("Key up detected");
});
```

There are a few ways of achieving the same result so I guess it's down to preference and depends on how you want it to work exactly.

Update: This only works for manual input not copy and paste.

For copy and paste I would recommend the following:

```
$('elementName').on('input',function(e){
 // Code here
});
```

Comment: I definitely recommend this one for text inputs!

Comment: Contents of input element can be changed without keyup being fired. For example you can paste text using mouse.

Comment: also, change seems to still be required to capture checkboxes

Comment: I never knew about the 'input' function. That's the one to use, IMO, since it supports manual text entry as well as cut/pasted text.

Answer (score 39):

Here's the code I use:

```
$("#tbSearch").on('change keyup paste', function () {
    ApplyFilter();
});

function ApplyFilter() {
    var searchString = $("#tbSearch").val();
    //  ... etc...
}

<input type="text" id="tbSearch" name="tbSearch" />
```

This works quite nicely, particularly when paired up with a `jqGrid` control.  You can just type into a textbox and *immediately* view the results in your `jqGrid`.

Answer (score 27):

There is **one and only one reliable way to do this**, and it is by pulling the value in an interval and comparing it to a cached value.

The reason why this is the only way is because there are multiple ways to change an input field using various inputs (keyboard, mouse, paste, browser history, voiceinput etc.) and you can never detect all of them using standard events in a cross-browser environment.

Luckily, thanks to the event infrastructure in jQuery, it’s quite easy to add your own inputchange event. I did so here:

```
$.event.special.inputchange = {
    setup: function() {
        var self = this, val;
        $.data(this, 'timer', window.setInterval(function() {
            val = self.value;
            if ( $.data( self, 'cache') != val ) {
                $.data( self, 'cache', val );
                $( self ).trigger( 'inputchange' );
            }
        }, 20));
    },
    teardown: function() {
        window.clearInterval( $.data(this, 'timer') );
    },
    add: function() {
        $.data(this, 'cache', this.value);
    }
};
```

Use it like: `$('input').on('inputchange', function() { console.log(this.value) });`

**There is a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/LGAWY/**

If you’re scared of multiple intervals, you can bind/unbind this event on `focus`/`blur`.

Comment: Is is possible to make your code work like this: `$('body').on('inputchange', 'input', function() { console.log(this.value) });`? Or not, as is mentioned here: https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/pull/98 ?

Comment: Writing and launching such a code is a madness with extreme performance impact.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech Please, tell me about it. But if you hit the focus/blur events as I also mentioned, the interval will only run temporarely. Surely, even an intel 386 from 1988 can handle a single interval?

Answer (score 7):

```
<input id="item123" class="firstName" type="text" value="Hello there" data-someattr="CoolExample" />

$(".firstName").on('change keyup paste', function () {
   var element = $(this);
   console.log(element);
   var dataAttribute = $(element).attr("data-someattr");
   console.log("someattr: " + dataAttribute );
});
```

I recommend use `this` keyword in order to get access to the entire element so your are able do everything you need with this element.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to trigger the event **as you type**, use the following:

```
$('input[name=myInput]').on('keyup', function() { ... });
```

If you want to trigger the event on **leaving the input field**, use the following:

```
$('input[name=myInput]').on('change', function() { ... });
```

Comment: For some reason this didn't work for me, but this did: `$(document).on('change', 'input[name=myInput]', function() { ... });`

Comment: @Stefan, the code in your example is called event delegation. Your input fields must have been adding up after the page initialization, that's why my code didn't work for you.

Answer (score 5):

The following will work even if it is dynamic/Ajax calls.

Script:

```
jQuery('body').on('keyup','input.addressCls',function(){
  console.log('working');
});
```

Html,

```
<input class="addressCls" type="text" name="address" value="" required/>
```

I hope this working code will help someone who is trying to access dynamically/Ajax calls...

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input").change(function () {
    alert("Changed!");
});
```

Comment: The problem of this option is that only works when you have lost the input focus

Comment: That will still fit some cases.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input").keyup(function () {
    alert("Changed!");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in different ways, **keyup** is one of them. But i am giving example below with on change.

```
$('input[name="vat_id"]').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).val().length == 0) {
        alert('Input field is empty');
    }
});
```

NB: **input[name="vat_id"]** replace with your input **ID** or **name**.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply work with the id

```
$("#your_id").on("change",function() {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't add much to the existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. If field with name **fieldA** is clicked or any key entered it updates field with id **fieldB**.

```
jQuery("input[name='fieldA']").on("input", function() {
    jQuery('#fieldB').val(jQuery(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`.keypress()`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/).

For example, consider the HTML:

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <input id="target" type="text" value="Hello there" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
```

The event handler can be bound to the input field:

```
$("#target").keypress(function() {
  alert("Handler for .keypress() called.");
});
```

I totally agree with Andy; all depends on how you want it to work.

Comment: This doesn't work for copy/paste operations.  No event is fired if text is pasted in with a mouse click.