# How can you detect a url in a text area using a javascript callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, url, callback

How can you detect a url in a textarea with JavaScript? With Facebook you can add a url and it will detect the address as soon as you finished pasting/typing it. How can this be done? I've done a lot of research on callback functions, etc. but am wondering how I can detect an actual url?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using jQuery the easiest way is with $.change().

Say you have a form field:

```
<input id="myField" type="text"/>
```

Now you can tie a change event to it, and at the same time find out if its a valid url:

```
$('#myField').keyup(function() {
    if(isUrl($(this).val()){
       //Show the url in an alert box
       alert($(this).val());
    }else{
       //do something if its not a url
    }
});
```

Then you would have a function that checks for a url and returns a boolean value.  Note, I took this from [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/452)

```
function isUrl(s) {
    var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
    return regexp.test(s);
}
```

Disclaimer:  I haven't tested any of the javascript, but this should give you a good idea of how you could accomplish this.

Comment: What represents the actual url? For instance if I wanted to have an alert I would say what? `alert(\\WHAT HERE?\\);`

Comment: don't use onchange event on this ... it will only trigger when blur the field (leave it), or send the form. Use onkeyup (see previous answer)

Answer (score 3):

Just handle `onkeyup` or similar event and then search the value of the textarea matching the regular expression. There's no special callback to catch event like "user wrote a link in a textarea" :-) So you have to catch existing events and handle it yourself.

Comment: onkeyup would be better. That way if they type example.com you can catch that when the last 'm' key is released, rather than when the next key is pressed.

Comment: ok, thanks. why somebody downvoted? Is it our job to write a code for people?? I think hint could be enough.

Answer (score 0):

The regex on previous answer doesn't match all possible URL because they are detected only if they begin with ftp, http or https, so `example.com` or `www.example.com` would not be found.

Also, the verification is made everytime you press a key so if you're writing an url like `example.com`, it will detect `example.co` then `example.com` which could be bad if you use it for extra information (like getting META of found URL).

`setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` help to reduce the frequency of verification

See :
[Run javascript function when user finishes typing instead of on key up?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5926782/1320311)

---

Here the code I end up with :

```js
var typingTimer;
var doneTypingInterval = 1000;

$(function() {
  // Check textarea on load
  checkTextareaUrl();

  // Check textarea on key pressed
  $('textarea').keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    typingTimer = setTimeout(checkTextareaUrl, doneTypingInterval);
  });
});

function checkTextareaUrl()
{
  var url = checkUrl($('textarea').val());

  if (url)
  {
    // Action when an url is found
    $('.url').text('Url found: '+ url);
  }
  else
  {
    // Action when an url is found
    $('.url').text('No url found');
  }
}

function checkUrl(string)
{
  var regex = /(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,63}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?/;
  return regex.test(string) ? string.match(regex)[0] : false;
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}

.url { font-weight: 700; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, example.com consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris at massa quis www.example.com metus sagittis sollicitudin. Donec posuere, enim quis tincidunt varius,  http://example.com nibh lorem vulputate massa, sed cursus lacus justo at ante. http://www.example.com</textarea>

<div class="url"></div>
```

---

If you need to get all URLs, you can use this function which return an array with all available URLs :

```
function checkUrls(string)
{
  var regex = /(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,63}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?/g;
  return regex.test(string) ? string.match(regex) : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea id="Testing" onkeypress="detectUrlExists" onblur="detectUrl" />


function detectUrlExists (event) {
    let urlIndex = event.target.value.match(/https:\/\//)?.index
    if (urlIndex) {
        //add lines to proceed after detecting url exists
    }
}

function detectUrl () {
    let val = document.getElementById('Testing').value
    let urls = val.split(' ').filter(el => el.startsWith('https://'))
}
```