# How to limit AJAX requests per custom time

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, request, limit

If I had a search box which loads suggestion on every keyup event. I think it would get worst for me server to respond on every request on every keyup event which could be about 10 times in a second or more. I mean there should be some AJAX request limiting functions that limit request(s) per sec(s) or any specific time. Can you tell me through coding examples on how to limit ajax request ?

Second thing, I would like to share that if we use JSP to limit AJAX request(s). Would it be a good idea being JSP a client side language and a malicious user could easily remove those ajax-request-limiting function(s) and doom the server.

OR ! Is there is any remedy for that ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: please don't put two unrelated queries in one question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wait for function till user stops typing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124114/wait-for-function-till-user-stops-typing)

Answer (score 2):

You can write a debounce method by your self:

```
var timer = null;
searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', function (evt) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        // this event listener will postpone its execution until after 1 second have elapsed since the last time it was invoked
        // send your ajax request here
    }, 1000);
}, false);
```

Or you can use [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#debounce) to limit keyup event:

```
searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', _.debounce(function (evt) {
    // this event listener will postpone its execution until after 1 second have elapsed since the last time it was invoked
}, 1000), false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a timer that will reset everytime an key event occurs. if no key was pressed until the timer is out , then send your ajax request.