# validating user input when user finished typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

what is the best way to validate user input for a a text field when the user is done typing?  I am using javascript/jquery.  is there a method that knows when the user has clicked out of the text field?

Answer (score 2):

Implement `onblur` event handler on the textfield which will be triggered when the user tabs out to next field.

Using jQuery,

```
$('.input_selector').on ('blur', function() {
    var inpValue = $(this).val();
    //validate Code
});
```

Comment: i can't help but notice that on the page load, this onblur automatically runs.  is there any way around this?

Comment: Do you set focus to any of the input elements? Try wrapping the code inside `$(function () { /*above code*/ });`

Comment: sorry, had autofocus on.  is there any way to get around this so i can do autofocus, without running the function to validate?  would i run a counter, so if it's 0, don't do anything ... else, validate?

Comment: @droidus On page load, Do you have focus set on one field and then you change focus to some other field? Yes, you can use a flag or counter to determine to avoid that

Comment: @droidus `onblur` event will be executed when a text field in focus loses its focus. If it complicated, simply use flag/counter as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

For all those who came here looking for a solution, please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220126/run-javascript-function-when-user-finishes-typing-instead-of-on-key-up#5926782).

Basically:

> The solution below solves this problem and will call X seconds after
>   finished as the OP requested. It also no longer requires the redundant
>   keydown function. I have also added a check so that your function call
>   won't happen if your input is empty.

```
//setup before functions
var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 5000;  //time in ms, 5 seconds for example

//on keyup, start the countdown
$('#myInput').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if ($('#myInput').val()) {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    }
});

//user is "finished typing", do something
function doneTyping() {
    //do something 
}
```

All credit for the guy who originally posted this answer, just copying in case somebody arrived here (as I did) looking for a solution.