# Disable submit button until form is valid

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form that is validated with the [bassistance validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation). It all works very well (great plugin by the way) but I would like to disable the submit button until the form is valid.

According to the author Jörn Zaefferer ([read comment here](http://old.nabble.com/Questions-Validation-Plugin-%28bassistance%29-td18072977s27240.html#a18096153)) I have to track the validity of all fields and then enable the button.

So I presume that I first have to find my all fields with a class name of 'required' and then check if they also have a class of 'valid', and then finally enable the button... but I am really struggling to do this (I have already spent 3.5 hours, it is driving me crazy!)

I tried to bind my input fields to listen for the 'valid' class using the timer technique that was [proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220126/run-javascript-function-when-user-finishes-typing-instead-of-on-key-up), and came up with the following:

```
function doneTyping () {

var requiredFields = $('input').hasClass('required');

$(requiredFields).each(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('valid')){
        console.log('form is valid, enable button here');
    } else {
        console.log('form is not valid yet');
    }
});
```

}

However my code doesn't work... Can someone please tell me if I am heading in the right direction?

Comment: When does the `doneTyping` function fire?

Answer (score 2):

```
function doneTyping () {

var requiredFields = $('input.required');

    if ($("input.required:not(:valid)").length){
        console.log('form is not valid, disable button here');
    } else {
        console.log('form is  valid ');
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I almost got it working now :)
There seem to be some kind of a delay on my textarea. I uploaded my code on jsfiddle if anyone would be so kind and take a look. (never mind my fugly css)
http://jsfiddle.net/WYB6N/3/

Much appreciated!

Comment: Ok so I figured out why the delay is - the validate class is not added until the blur event fires. Now I just need to figure out a way around this!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if form is valid using the below idea according to ur plugin

```
alert (($("#Form1").validationEngine('validate')));
```

This will give you a true or false value, and based on that you can show or hide the button.

Initially hide the button using:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $("#ButtonSubmit).hide();
}
```

Comment: Wrong validate plugin, sorry! :)

Comment: @Ryley  I was just giving her an idea unlike u down voting others help ..gr8 job

Comment: Well, I don't know how to solve this problem, but I do know that your answer suggests using a completely different plugin, so your answer is useless at best, misleading at worst.  That's what [downvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#behonest) are for, it's nothing personal!