# How to control input values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I use 2 same inputs at search form. I want to control data typing. For example, user enter time or price in any interval. Second value must be larger than first.
**How to make user can not enter larger value to second field?**

For date:

```
@Html.TextBox( "date1", string.Empty, new { @class = "dateClass", type_datepicker = "true", @id = "datepicker" } )
@Html.TextBox( "date2", string.Empty, new { @class = "dateClass", type_datepicker = "true", @id = "datepicker2" } )
```

and for price:

```
@Html.TextBox( "price1", string.Empty, new { @class = "priceClass" } )
@Html.TextBox( "price2", string.Empty, new { @class = "priceClass" } )
```

*date1* and *date2* are string, *price1* and *price2* are double. Sorry for my bad english..

Comment: This looks like ASP.NET MVC. Have you considered using validators? You could write a custom validator attribute and then decorate your view model property with it.

Comment: But, I dont use any model. Products have Date and Price properties.I send paramaters to this Action method:

public ActionResult Search( string date1, string date2, double? price1, double? price2 ){}

Comment: Oh that's your problem: you should use a view model.

Comment: Is it not possible on view without model? with jquery, javascript or others..

Comment: Of course that it's possible, but don't you wanna use what's already built into the framework? If you don't want to use unobtrusive validation you could manually write your jquery.validate rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tweak this so it matches whatever your backend code is returning back

You have a few options here, you can either validate when the user submits the form or when the user stops typing.  At submit is pretty straight forward

```
if ($('#second').val() > $('#first').val()){
      return false;
   }
```

For comparing dates, [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-2-dates-with-javascript)

Or you can do it when user stops typing, thanks to  [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220126/run-javascript-function-when-user-finishes-typing-instead-of-on-key-up)  you can do this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 1000;  //time in ms, 1 second for example

 //on keyup, start the countdown
$('#second').keyup(function(){
    typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
 });

 //on keydown, clear the countdown
    $('#second').keydown(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
  });

 //user is "finished typing," do something
  function doneTyping () {
     if ($('#second').val() > $('#first').val()){
      alert('cannot do that');        //take whatever action you need here
   }
  }
});
```

Also, for datepickers, if you are using [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), there is an option to specify disabling certain date ranges, so you can use that to disable anything earlier than the value of the first datepicker (but again all that is just client side checks, if this is crucial to your application you will have to do back-end checks as well in C# or whatever language you are using)