# Chosen.js Performance

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to use chosen.js for a list with about 1400 entries. It is taking about 1.5 seconds to run the initialisation code for chosen.

Have tracked down that in `SelectParser.prototype.add_option()` the slow part is `html: option.innerHTML`

```
 this.parsed.push({
     array_index: this.parsed.length,
     options_index: this.options_index,
     value: option.value,
     text: option.text,
     html: option.innerHTML,  // <======= here
     selected: option.selected,
     disabled: group_disabled === true ? group_disabled : option.disabled,
     group_array_index: group_position,
     classes: option.className,
     style: option.style.cssText                  
    });
```

If this is set to simply `html: option.text` the chosen plugin still seems to work as required.

Are there other implications to changing this & any other tips to improve performance?

Comment: In which browser does it take 1.5 second ? 1400 entries is really big amount of data/html, and can slow down chosen initialization significantly. You should consider ajax solution (combined with autocomplete), check this link for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044330/jquery-chosen-plugin-dynamically-populate-list-by-ajax . Some time ago I had similar performance problems and my general conclusion is: JS DOM manipulation is very slow in many browsers, the best way to avoid it is portioning data and it's interaction with frontend.

Answer (score 2):

While HTML serialization is generally a slow operation, I find it surprising that it is supposedly responsible for more than a second delay. A quick test I've run has shown that executing `option.innerHTML` on 5000 options takes less than 2 milliseconds in Firefox 33 and Chrome 38, other browsers should behave similarly. So I have a suspicion that you identified the source of the issue incorrectly.

Either way, your change has two implications:

1. Any formatting of the options will be lost, chosen.js will only display pure text. Given that most of the time options *are* only pure text, that might not be something you care about.
2. The option text will be inserted as HTML code. This will cause trouble whenever special characters like `<` are used, this is also a potential source of security issues ([XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)). To prevent this your code should contain escaping:

```js
 html: option.text.replace("&", "&amp").replace("<", "&lt;").replace(">", "&gt;"),
```

Comment: At least it got my script a little faster.