# Combine Jquery UI Autocomplete with Jquery Chosen for a Stackoverflow styling of my tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-autocomplete, jquery-chosen

Currently I am successfully using jquery ui autocomplete with acts_as_taggable_on rails gem.

However, I want my tags to be displayed like they are on StackOverFlow when you ask a question with an X mark that can be clicked to remove them.

For this I want to use [Chosen](https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails)

Into gemfile:

```
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'chosen-rails'
```

Into app/assets/javascripts/application.js if use with jQuery

```
//= require chosen-jquery
```

Into app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
*= require chosen-compass
```

No I need to call the .chosen function on the id/class of the form. But I have not gotten it to work at all. Here is my form:

```
<%= form_for :photo, url: photos_path, html: {multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :picture %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %> 
  <%= f.autocomplete_field :tag_list, autocomplete_tag_name_photos_path, :placeholder => 'Tags', :"data-delimiter" => ', ', 'data-auto-focus' => true %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Inspect the tags input box with Chrome Developer Tools

```
<input placeholder="Tags" data-delimiter=", " data-auto-focus="true" data-autocomplete="/photos/autocomplete_tag_name" type="text" name="photo[tag_list]" id="photo_tag_list" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
```

Can you please provide me with the correct script to apply .chosen to this form?

Here is my attempt at the jquery to call chosen:

```
$(document).on('page:change', function () { 
  $('#photo_tag_list').chosen
    allow_single_deselect: true;
    no_results_text: 'No results matched';
    width: '200px';
});
```

Edit: It occurred to me that I could do the css myself if I can figure out how to put the submitted tags inside of their own element such as a ul/li.

Comment: just to confirm, your autocomplete field is working fine yes?

Comment: Yes, the jquery ui autocomplete works

Comment: you want to try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044330/jquery-chosen-plugin-dynamically-populate-list-by-ajax first and see if it helps you?

Comment: I don't know how to apply that question to my own.

Comment: Right, in that case, can you paste the js code to initialize autocomplete functionality?I can then have a crack on it

Comment: please see edited question

Comment: Here is the github for jquery ui autocomplete. https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete

Comment: perhaps the part about 'Running custom code on selection' would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, however an easier solution is to use select2 gem with acts_as_taggable_on gem to create StackOverFlow style tagging system.

https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails