# yadcf Is it possible to give each option a separate data soruce? And refresh?

Tags: javascript, datatables, yadcf

DataTable initialisation, give it the server url location

```js
oTable = $('.entrys_table').DataTable({
     "processing": true,
     "serverSide": true,
     "ajax": {
          "url": "entrys_table_server_side_source",
          "type": "POST"
     },
     "language": {
          "infoFiltered": " - filtered from _MAX_ records"
     },
     "columns": [
          { data: "engine" },
          { data: "browser" },
     ]
})

yadcf.init(oTable, [
     {
          column_number: 0,
          filter_container_id: 'account1',
          filter_type: 'select',
     },
     {
          column_number: 1,
          filter_container_id: 'account2',
          filter_type: 'select',
     },
], { externally_triggered: true });
```

**But I would like to ask how to make yadcf URL location is different?**

**More hope is that each option can have a separate URL location?**

**And let the option can be updated independently of the data (again to the server to get the latest information)**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible way that can I think of is to use yadcf along with third party select plugin (chosen / select2) and load its data using ajax

Something like [Jquery Chosen plugin - dynamically populate list by Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044330/jquery-chosen-plugin-dynamically-populate-list-by-ajax) or [Select2 Ajax (remote data)](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax)

In addition please take a look at the following issue that was eventually resolved and looks like it might be useful for you 
 [ajax populated fields + externally_triggered + server_side removing fields value](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/239)