# MySQL & AJAX Predictive Search Implementation Options

Tags: sql, ajax, jquery, sql-like

I have addresses in an "address" table in a MySQL database.  The table contains an address ID column and the usual assortment of address-related columns - name, line 1, line 2, suburb, state, postcode, etc.  A number of the fields allow NULL.

This is used in a client side web-based interface - the user can find and select an address from the table by typing any part of it into a text box.  Matches are displayed and the user can select one.

[image: The Airport is listed because of the 'str' in Australia]

The terms in the text box are treated as a space-delimited series of search terms, and that each one of the terms must be present in any of the address fields for it to show up for selection.

[image: Now there are two search terms to match...]

I'm torn between a few implementation methods for this:

The current method:

1. On page load, an asynchronous HTTP request ("AJAX") is used to retrieve ALL addresses in a nicely formatted list (all fields combined into a single line, accounting for blank fields).
2. jQuery is used to find and display matches in this list whenever the text box receives input.

The benefit of this approach is that only one simple query needs to be sent, and there's no delay between typing into the search field and seeing the responses since the searching is done on the client side (although this may not scale well - see below).  It also avoids the need for complex SQL searching (which I'm not averse to, I just wanted to implement something as a proof of concept and this method was quicker).

The downside is of course that the page must retrieve every address when the page is loaded, and the database is likely to end up storing thousands of addresses.

The alternative method would be to send a HTTP request whenever the user types into the text box, which would return the addresses matching a search of the table using SQL.  Requires more requests and greater delays, but only needs to retrieve and transfer a subset of addresses each time.  I can easily tweak the minimum term length and polling frequency as needed.

I'm wondering about the best way to implement the SQL side of this...

Would I be best off creating a view which concatenates all searchable address columns and using a query with a WHERE clause along the lines of "concatcolumn LIKE '%term1%' AND concatcolumn LIKE '%term2%' AND concatcolumn LIKE '%termN%'"?

Any ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come to a solution that I'm fairly happy with.

Firstly created a view containing the searchable address fields concatenated:

```
CREATE VIEW address_concat AS
SELECT address_id, CONCAT_WS(' ', address_name, address_line_1, address_line_2, suburb, postcode, state, country) AS full_address
FROM address
```

When a request with a search string is received, I parse it in PHP and use the view to find matches (the following code is cleaned up and removes non-relevant things - the data is sanitised, etc):

```
$terms = explode(' ', preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $_GET['find_address'])); //get array of terms  
$where = " WHERE full_address LIKE '%".implode("%' AND full_address LIKE '%", $terms)."%' "; //turn array into WHERE clause

//query database to find matches
$result = $db->query("SELECT a.* FROM address a JOIN address_concat ac ON a.address_id = ac.address_id ".$where." ORDER BY IFNULL(IF(address_name = '', NULL, address_name), address_line_1)");

if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{       
    //construct output
    $output = '<ul>';

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        $output .= '<li val_id="'.$row['address_id'].'">'.make_address(...).'</li>';

    $output .= '</ul>';
}
else
    $output = '<p>No matches found.</p>';
```

On the client side, I used some wisdom from [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220126/run-javascript-function-when-user-finishes-typing-instead-of-on-key-up) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042193/how-to-trigger-an-event-in-input-text-after-i-stop-typing-writting) to make it only query after a pause in typing.

```
var typingTimer;

$('input#filterbox').bind('input', function () 
{
    var textfield = $(this);

    //code to hide/show "clear text field" box eliminated, etc

    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    typingTimer = setTimeout(function () {doFilterUpdate(textfield);}, 750);

});

function doFilterUpdate (target)
{
    if (target.val().length >= 3)
        $('div#resultlist').load('inc/ajax.php?find_address=' + encodeURIComponent(target.val()));
    else
        $('div#resultlist').html('');
}
```

I'm still not certain if creating the view is necessary/more efficient than just writing a query on the address table that uses CONCAT_WS in the WHERE clause... it does make the query a lot simpler, though :P

Answer (score 0):

Definitely do not bring back the addresses before searching, users won't mind the second it takes to return results, use a loading gif to showing something is happening during your ajax call.

Do something like:

```
SELECT columns
FROM   table
WHERE     searchterm LIKE '%' + column1 + '%'
       OR searchterm LIKE '%' + column2 + '%'
       OR searchterm LIKE '%' + column3 + '%'
```

I would also be tempted to use the `REPLACE` function to remove spaces, commas and fullstops

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(searchterm,' ',''),',',''),'.','') LIKE '%' + column1 + '%'
```

I would also be tempted to place a limit on the number of results returned by using the keyword [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/limit-optimization.html) after the end of the query.

Comment: A search like that (although assuming you mixed up the term/column placeholders) would need to account for multiple search terms and search for them in every field... e.g. "(col1 LIKE term1 OR col2 LIKE term1) AND (col1 LIKE term2 OR col2 LIKE term2)"...  Hence why I'm wondering if a view with all searchable columns concatenated into one would be worthwhile...

Comment: In that case you will need to split the search term by spaces and do column1 LIKE '%' + searchterm1 + '%' etc. instead