# How to capture events in Javascript textarea for recording all typed text

Tags: javascript

I am sorry to post such a general question with little code but all googling has been unsuccessful.

I want to record the process of a document being created entirely, I am making this "document editor"

If someone types `Hello world` and then backspaces the last 5 chars and then types `Joe` I want the result to be `Hello Joe` displayed to the user but in my array I want the following stored:

```
record[0] = 'H';
record[1] = 'e';
record[2] = 'l';
record[3] = 'l';
record[4] = 'o';
record[5] = ' ';
record[6] = 'w';
record[7] = 'o';
record[8] = 'r';
record[9] = 'l';
record[10] = 'd';
record[11] = 'Backspace';
record[12] = 'Backspace';
record[13] = 'Backspace';
record[14] = 'Backspace';
record[15] = 'Backspace';
record[16] = 'J';
record[17] = 'o';
record[18] = 'e';
```

My Code so far:

```
function recordTextArea()
{
  // Record all text

  var record = [];

}
```

I have searched for ways to capture all this information but I just can't make it out.

I want the program to be able to record this so that I can play back the document.

I am trying to create a pure Javascript solution.

EDIT: All I need help with is capturing keypresses and their values in a textarea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In plain JavaScript what you want is this:

```
var record = [];

document.getElementById('my_txt').onkeyup = function(e){
    record.push(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
};
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9xSrc/)

But this captures all key codes (including non-printable keys). Additionally it captures characters without knowing the case of the character (you'd have to check the state of shift and capslock keys separately). One more problem is that this code is vulnerable to undo/redo operations.

Keeping this in mind you'd be better off reading the textarea content and saving the difference as previous state like this:

```
theTextArea.onkeyup = function(e){
    var value = new String(theTextArea.value);
    if ( record.length ) {
        var prev = record[record.length - 1];
        var diff = value.length - prev.length;
        var newEntry = {
            length: value.length
        };
        if ( diff < 0 ) {
            newEntry.txtDiff = diff;
        }
        else {
            newEntry.txtDiff = value.substring(value.length - diff);
        }
        record.push(newEntry);       
    }
    else {
        record.push({
            txtDiff: value,
            length: value.length
        });
    }
};
```

The data structure in the later example alows you to freely manipulate revisions of the text in the textarea. [See it live here](http://jsfiddle.net/9c52d/8/).

**EDIT:**

Additionally you can implement an *stop typing* event instead of `keyup`. This will decrease both: memory and cpu usage. Since this is out of the scope of this question, you can read about it elswhere on SO, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14042239/1697320).

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery, you can just do:

```
$( function() {
  var record = [];
  $( "#myText" ).on( "keypress", function( evt ) {
    record.push( String.fromCharCode( evt.which ) );
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know if I am asking too much for a pure Javascript, no external libraries solution?

Comment: Please read [this reference about JavaScript keyboard events across browsers](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html). You can see why you might not want to do this without a library - browsers can't agree on what key is what! jQuery normalizes this all with its `event.which`.

Comment: Especially in `3.2. Classic Values Returned on Character Events` and `3.3. Key Code Values` gives you an overview of what you need to achieve this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

```
var txtarea = document.getElementById('txtarea'),
    record = [];

txtarea.addEventListener('keydown', recordTextArea);

function recordTextArea(e){
    record.push(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
}
```

Comment: Please note that this is not cross-browser compatible - [different browsers will report different keys](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html). Also, `keydown` will only get the key code - not the actual character code. It won't differentiate between 'a' and 'A'.

Comment: I agree but he wanted pure JS. With a little bit more digging he can work around it. @Cuberto

Comment: Sure, but it won't work across browsers without a lot of work and doesn't get the actual character code, just the key code. IE versions less than 9 also don't support `event.which`.

Comment: I was just gonna say it's mainly IE < 9 that has this issue. I'm not disagreeing with you here. I'm saying I answered what he wanted. He is free to not accept it. @Cuberto

Comment: I have an issue, my characters are being recorded as capital letters.

Comment: Ok I get it, my characters are just key presses, how can I tell if caps lock or shift is on?

Answer (score 1):

Simple as mentioned @Cuberto

```
var record = [];
document.getElementById("mytextBox").onkeypress=
   function(event){
   record.push( String.fromCharCode( event.which ) );
};
```