# React + Redux - Input onChange is very slow when typing in when the input have a value from the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I got my input who is filled by a value from my state.

```
<input id="flashVars" name="flashVars" type="text" value={settings.flashVarsValue} disabled={isDisabled} onChange={handleChange} />
```

`Settings`is my state with Redux. When i put a value into my input, i must specify a `onChange` function. This is my onChange function:

```
handleFlashVarsChange(e) {
  let { dispatch } = this.props;

  dispatch( changeFlashVarsValue(e.target.value) );
}
```

It change the state value `flashVarsValue` for the value of the input. But when i type in my input, it lags. I don't understand why i should call the dispatch each time i change the input value.

Is there any way who can give less lags?

My reducer:

```
import { ACTIONS } from '../utils/consts';

const initialState = {
  ...
  flashVarsValue: '',
  ...
};

export function formSettings(state = initialState, action = '') {
  switch (action.type) {

    ...

    case ACTIONS.CHANGE_FLASHVARS_VALUE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        flashVarsValue: action.data
      });

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

My action:

```
export function changeFlashVarsValue(data) {
  return {
    type: ACTIONS.CHANGE_FLASHVARS_VALUE,
    data: data
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Is this lag with the redux dev-tools or without? Try it without first and see if that helps.

Comment: I dont use the redux dev-tools yet, i just began using it

Comment: Can you show the code updating your store?  I'm not confident I'm seeing enough code in order to help you.

Comment: I just updated my post about this

Comment: It looks okay and I don't think it's the reason for lags.

Comment: The reason for `value` + `onChange` is in the docs, "Controlled Components" section: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: Every time i type  a letter, it launch the event...

Comment: I know these docs, but i work with redux :S The state is managed another way

Comment: were you using `react-chrome-redux`? to connect the component to a redux store in the background page of a chrome extension?

Comment: https://github.com/DWboutin/react-webpack-startup/blob/master/src/middlewares/reactRouting.jsx check this setup, apply 'redux-devtools-extension' middleware

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had a similar problem when I was editing a grid with a million rows, so what I did was to change the update logic, in your case `handleChange` to be called only on the event `onBlur` instead of `onChange`. This will only trigger the update when you lose focus. But don't know if this would be a satisfactory solution for you.

Comment: Thank you ill try it monday ;)

Comment: @MikeBoutin did it work for you? i have the same issue

Comment: Try to manage the update with shouldComponentUpdate, it worked for me

Comment: What do you mean "manage the update with shouldComponentUpdate"?

Comment: Not sure if I'm the only person with this issue, but if I use `onBlur` instead of `onChange`, the field does not update as I type.

Comment: If you use `onBlur` instead of `onChange` in any input and set the property `value` you have to use `defaultValue` instead. This way it will work for controlled components. Also remember that every time the input is blurred, the function will be called. [Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/q380ywxo26)

Comment: The `onBlur` thingy works well, but `defaultValue` behaves weirdly. I use it inside a controlled component and even if the prop value is certainly null, the amount shown on the screen remains somehow cached to the previous value.

Comment: Most underrated answer on SO. You're the best @luanped.

Comment: this is working, but the question IS THIS THE BEST SOLUTION yet?

Comment: @besseddrest same here. since im downloading data, the defaultValue starts as null, but im not sure why it does not update once the value is populated.

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is possibly re-renders. You're passing in "settings" (your entire state) to your component containing the "input", and we don't know how the rest of your connected components are coupled to state. Check to see if as a result of the state object mutating,  you're rerendering much more than just the input on every keystroke. The solution to this is to more directly pass in the specific parts of state you need from mapStateToProps (in this case, maybe only pass in "flashVarsValue" if that's all this component needs, and make sure other components aren't also passed the whole state) and use PureRenderMixin or Dan Abramov's https://github.com/gaearon/react-pure-render if you're using ES6 components to not re-render if your props haven't changed

Answer (score 4):

The answer for me was to use the shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle hook. This has already been given as an answer in a comment by Mike Boutin (about a year ago :) ), but an example might help the next visitor here.

I had a similar problem, with the text input being lost, and slow and jumpy. I was using setState to update the formData in my onChange event.

I found that the form was doing a complete re-render with every keypress, as the state had changed. So to stop this, I overrode the function:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
   return this.state.formErrors !== nextState.formErrors);
}
```

I show an error notification panel on form submission with any new or changed validation errors, and that's the only time I need to re-render.

If you have no child components, you could probably just set the form component's shouldComponentUpdate to always return false.

Comment: From react documentation "This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a rendering, as this can lead to bugs." (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

Comment: I believe event handler execution will be first in order before shouldCompomentUpdate, so this will not work in all cases.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but if you want to fire onChange on a text input, you probably want to debounce your event. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js) does a good job breaking it down, but I think this would work for the op's example:

```
import debounce from 'debounce'                                      

function debounceEventHandler(...args) {
  const debounced = debounce(...args)
  return function (e) {
    e.persist();
    return debounced(e);
  }
}                                                                      
const Container = React.createClass({
  handleFlashVarsChange(e) {
    let { dispatch } = this.props;
    //basic redux stuff
    this.props.changeFlashVarsValue(e.target.value));
  },
  render() {
    const handleChange = debounceEventHandler(this.handleFlashVarsChange, 15);
    return (
      <input id="flashVars" onChange={handleChange} />
    )
  }                                                                         
}
//...prep and return your redux container
```

Comment: I was thinking about this - BUT - if your debounce sets state after 1 second, and your input relies on a change in state to update (re-render), wouldn't  you have to wait 1 second to see 'foo' change to 'bar', for example? You wouldn't actually see the individual 'b', 'ba', 'bar' changes, would you?

Comment: this only works with uncontrolled components, if you use a controlled component and the value is debounced, the input won't update.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is not to re-render your component on every key stroke, only if user stops typing in. Something like this:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (!textInputReRender)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

onTextInputChange = (propName, propValue) => {
    if (inputChangeTimerId)
        clearTimeout(inputChangeTimerId);

    inputChangeTimerId = setTimeout(() => {
        inputChangeTimerId = null;
        const newState = {};

        textInputReRender = true;

        newState[propName] = propValue;
        this.setState(newState);
    }, 500);

    textInputReRender = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `onChangeText` instead

```
import { TextInput, View} from "react-native";  
import { connect } from "react-redux"; 
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";

function SearchTextInput(props) {
  const { keyword = "", setKeyword } = props; 
  return (
     <TextInput
       style={styles.searchInputText}
       placeholder={"placeholder here"}
       value={keyword}
       onChangeText={setKeyword(t)}
     />
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    keyword: state.search.keyword,
    search: state.search
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setKeyword: payload => dispatch(({type:'updateSearchText', keyword: payload }))
});
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SearchTextInput);
```

Comment: Never talked about react-native here.

Comment: @MikeBoutin, it save my work on react-native :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem is common happen when you have a complex page, that need re-render always that you update the state. So you can percept that is very slow when typing.

I found a solution: The cycle of life of react run by component. So you can create other component and manage yours events, like onChange, after you can call onBlur, that is passed by props for him.  It worked for me:

```
import React, {Fragment, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';


export function InputText(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const {onBlur = (e) => {console.log(e)}, name='name', defaultValue= 'Default', type='text', label='Label'} = props

  useEffect(() => {

    // console.log(value);
  })

  return (
      <label>
        <TextField 
          name={name} 
          label={label}  
          onBlur={e => onBlur(e)}
          type={type}
          value={value}
          onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
  );
}


class Sample extends React.Component {
    handleBlurInput = e => {        
         this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };
  render() {
    return (
    <InputText name="nome" label="Label Sample" defaultValue={this.state.nome} onBlur={this.handleBlurInput.bind(this)} />

    // Complex app ....
    );
  }
}
```