# How to reduce delay while typing in text field in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

```
// InputField.jsx

import React from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { setValue } from '../action/setValue.action'
import { Form, FormItem, FormInput } from 'react-blueprint'

export const InputField = (props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const onChange = (e) => {
        const val = e.target.value
        dispatch(setValue('inputField', val)) // dispatches setValue action which updates inputField variable on store
    }

    return (
        <Form>
            <FormItem 
                render={() => 
                    <FormInput 
                        value={props.selector?.inputField}
                        onChange={onChange}
                    />
                }
            />
        </Form>
    )
}
```

Above is code of my `InputField.jsx`, which dispatches `setValue` action to update the variable on store. On each key stroke dispatch happens and component re renders with updated value which causes lag while typing fast.

```
// InputField.jsx

import React, from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { setValue } from '../action/setValue.action'
import { Form, FormItem, FormInput } from 'react-blueprint'

export const InputField = (props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const [input, setInput] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch(setValue('inputField', val)) // dispatches setValue action which updates inputField variable on store
        }, 0)
    }, [input])

    const onChange = (e) => {
        const val = e.target.value
        setInput(val)
    }

    return (
        <Form>
            <FormItem 
                render={() => 
                    <FormInput 
                        value={input}
                        onChange={onChange}
                    />
                }
            />
        </Form>
    )
}
```

Above is the code that I've tried to reduce the lag and it's working, but I have Edit Button which populates the `inputValue` on store on click and I want to populate the my `input` variable with value which is in store using `setInput`. I tried many ways but it throws error stating `too many re-renders`.

```
// Edit.jsx

import React from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { Button } from 'react-blueprint'

export function Edit(item) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const handleEdit = () => {
        dispatch(setValue('inputField', item.InputField)) // dispatches setValue action which updates inputField variable on store
        window.scrollTo(800, 0)
    }
    
    return (
        <Button
            onClick={handleEdit}
        >
        edit
        </Button>
    )
}
```

How to handle this case ? Is there any other way to reduce the lag while typing ? 
Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React + Redux - Input onChange is very slow when typing in when the input have a value from the state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33266156/react-redux-input-onchange-is-very-slow-when-typing-in-when-the-input-have-a)

Comment: @James Thank you for the reply. Yes it did work to solve the delay problem but when I click on the edit it's not populating the edit value. I'm still figuring out why it's not working and I think it's due to use of `defaultValue` instead of `value`

Comment: @James Observed one thing when there was already some value typed in the input field and I clicked on the edit it was not working, input field not populating with the new edit value.

Comment: @James `defaultValue` is used for uncontrolled input, but in my case it is controlled input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using `useRef` hook and `onBlur` instead of `onChange`.

```
// InputField.jsx

import React, { useEffect, useRef }from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { setValue } from '../action/setValue.action'
import { Form, FormItem, FormInput } from 'react-blueprint'

export const InputField = (props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const inputRef = useRef(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        inputRef.current.value = props.selector?.inputField
    }, [props.selector?.editClicked]) // sets the value of input field when edit is clicked

    const onBlur = (e) => {
        dispatch(setValue('inputField', inputRef.current.value)) // dispatches setValue action which updates inputField variable on store
    }

    return (
        <Form>
            <FormItem 
                render={() => 
                    <FormInput 
                        ref={inputRef}
                        onBlur={onBlur}
                    />
                }
            />
        </Form>
    )
}
```

```
// Edit.jsx

import React from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { Button } from 'react-blueprint'

export function Edit(item) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const handleEdit = () => {
        dispatch(setValue('inputField', item.InputField)) // dispatches setValue action which updates inputField variable on store
        setTimeOut(() => {
            window.scrollTo(800, 0)
            dispatch(toggleEditclicked()) // toggles editClicked variable on store when edit is clicked
        })
        
    }
    
    return (
        <Button
            onClick={handleEdit}
        >
        edit
        </Button>
    )
}
```