# How I can disable a button in React js for 5 seconds after click event

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react. I need help in disabling a button for 5 seconds in react js for my project and then re enable it back.

here is my code,

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.onLaunchClicked = this.onLaunchClicked.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        isButtonDisabled: false
    }
}

onLaunchClicked (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        isButtonDisabled: true
    });
    return this.props.onLaunchClicked();

}

       render () {
    return (
        <div className="client-playtest-state">
            <button className="btn bg-success" onClick={this.onLaunchClicked} 
         disabled={this.state.isButtonDisabled}>LAUNCH</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Share what have done so far.

Comment: You can timeout for 5 seconds. And please share code sample of what u have. We are not here to code for you.

Comment: Sorry I missed to add the code,

Comment: Related post - [ReactJs: Prevent multiple times button press](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35315872/465053)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) and update the `state` back after a timeout.

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.onLaunchClicked = this.onLaunchClicked.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        isButtonDisabled: false
    }
}

onLaunchClicked (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        isButtonDisabled: true
    });

    // **** here's the timeout ****
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ isButtonDisabled: false }), 5000);

    return this.props.onLaunchClicked();

}

render () {
    return (
        <div className="client-playtest-state">
            <button className="btn bg-success" onClick={this.onLaunchClicked} 
         disabled={this.state.isButtonDisabled}>LAUNCH</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much for the answer :)

Answer (score 5):

**There are many ways to do it.**

Here is my example:

React.js provides build in function called [ComponentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

Use build in [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

method. Wit this method, you will be able to call React.js setState.

Here is not tested example of it:

```
componentDidMount(){
 window.setTimeout(function () {
     this.setState({
         isButtonDisabled: false,
     })
 },5000)
}
```

If I understood your question correctly, this will work. After a user joins the site he will need to wait for 5 sec.

Please read React documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
let myInterval, disableOTPmilliseconds = 5000;

const sendOtp = async () => {
try {
  if (userSessionData?.phone?.toString().trim()) {
     const res = await axios.post(
       `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT}/api/users/send_otp`,
       userSessionData
     );

    setDisableOtpButton(true);

    myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      return setDisableTimer((prev) => prev - 1);
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      setDisableOtpButton(false);
      setDisableTimer(disableOTPmilliseconds / 1000); // using disableOTPmilliseconds variable to define or change the milliseconds.

      clearInterval(myInterval);
    }, disableOTPmilliseconds); 
  }
```

};