# How to prevent a double click in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working on search filter in **ReactJS** and I face a problem. Problem is about when User does some search and wants to click on `next` (because I have pagination in app) then the User will click twice to load other pages of data.

I need to avoid this behaviour: I mean when user does single click on `next` it should be "load a data" instead of "double click".

I am new to ReactJS, please expert help me

**Code**

```js
    btnClick() {
        const { Item,skip , filtered, data } = this.state
        if(filtered.length>0 || !data.length ){
          window.alert("Hello,")
          this.setState({
            filtered:[],
            skip:0
          },()=>this.getData());
          return false
        }else {
          window.alert("Hello , Dear")
        this.setState(
          {
            Item,
            skip: skip + pageSize
          },
          () => this.getData()
        );}

      }
```

Comment: on click disable the button, then when data returns re enable it.

Comment: Duplicated -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315872/reactjs-prevent-multiple-times-button-press

Answer (score 5):

You can have a `isLoading` state and set the `disabled` prop on the `button` when in this state which will not allow the button to be clicked again while the data is being fetched.

```js
 btnClick() {
   const {
     Item,
     skip,
     filtered,
     data
   } = this.state;
   
   if (filtered.length > 0 || !data.length) {
     window.alert("Hello,")
     this.setState({
       filtered: [],
       skip: 0
     }, () => this.fetchData());
     return false
     
   } else {
     window.alert("Hello , Dear")
     this.setState({
         Item,
         skip: skip + pageSize
       },
       () => this.fetchData()
     );
   }
 }
 
 fetchData() = async() => {
     this.setState({ isLoading: true });
     
     await this.getData();
     
     this.setState({ isLoading: false });
 }
 
 render() {
        const {
      isLoading
    } = this.state;
    
    const buttonProps = isLoading ? { disabled: true} ? {};
    
    return (
      <button onClick={this.btnClick} { ...buttonProps }>
            Click to fetch
      </button>
    );
 }
```