# How to disable a button after clicking?

Tags: html, reactjs

I am saving a value through a textfield and after the button click, I wanted to disable the button so the user can't press it again.

I am using React.js for the implementation of the app.

```
<button type="button" className="btn btn-info round btn-glow px-2 float-right">Confirm</button>
```

Comment: You need a handler function for click event, and a variable to save current state, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49642037/4504053

Comment: Please show us some code you have tried.

Comment: You should use a form and look for `onSubmit` event of the form instead of `onClick` of the button. You know people can submit by hitting enter too.

Answer (score 1):

create a state like this

```
state = {
    btnIsDisable: false
}
```

set in button

```
<button disabled={this.state.btnIsDisable} type="button" className="btn btn-info round btn-glow px-2 float-right">Confirm</button>
```

in onClick handler change the state

```
this.setState({btnIsDisable:true});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a class component and set the initial state button state to true and then change it to false when the click function is fired

```
// Initial state
this.state = {
    buttonEnabled : true
};


// onClick function
onClick(event){
    this.setState({buttonEnabled: false});   
}

   render() {
     const { buttonEnabled } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick} disabled={buttonEnabled}>
          Your content here
        <button>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// declare some variable for holding your button's state
state = {
  disabled: false
}

...

onConfirmButtonClick () => {
  // set state.disabled as true
  this.setState({ disabled: true })
}


render () {
  return (

    ...

    <button
      disabled={this.state.disabled} // add disabled attribute to your button along with your state
      type="button"
      className="btn btn-info round btn-glow px-2 float-right"
    >
      Confirm
    </button>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code in the link: https://codepen.io/stanlee94/pen/gNOLxb

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  state = {
    disabled: false,
    pointerStyle: 'pointer'
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    //Do your logic here
    console.log('Record added');
    this.setState({
      disabled: true,
      pointerStyle: 'no-drop'
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
    <button disabled={this.state.disabled} type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}
      style={{ cursor: this.state.pointerStyle }}>Confirm</button>
    );
  }
}
```

It will add an invalid type of pointer after you click to provide a good user experience to your user.