# Disabling Submit button on click with useRef (to prevent double clicks) inside a Formik form causes Formik submission to break

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a Formik form as below, and it works OK in its original implementation. One extra feature I had to add is that when the Submit button is clicked, I have to disable it, to prevent double-clicks. I followed the [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315872/reactjs-prevent-multiple-times-button-press) which is to define a `ref={submitBtnRef}` on a button. But after inserting this code in the `onClick`, Formik doesn't submit anymore, it just stops. If I remove this new code everything works. There are no validation errors; I output Formik's `errors` and it's empty. Also no console errors.

```
const submitForm = async (formValues) => {
    const url = '/app/submitAgreement';
    let obj = {'formValues': formValues};
    await axios.post(url, obj);
}

// Define a Submit Button Ref for disabling in Submit's onClick() below
let submitBtnRef = useRef();

<Formik 
    enableReinitialize
    validationSchema={mySchema} 
    onSubmit={ (values) => {
        submitForm(values); // Calls submitForm() function if there are no errors
    }}
    initialValues={initialFormValues}
>
    {
        ({handleSubmit, handleChange, handleBlur, setFieldValue, setFieldTouched, values, touched, isValid, errors}) 
        => (

            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> {/* Form starts here */}
            ..
            ..
            <Button type="submit" ref={submitBtnRef}
                    onClick={() => { 
                       // If I remove this Ref-Disable code it works, but I need to disable Submit
                       if(submitBtnRef.current) {
                          submitBtnRef.current.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
                       }
            
                       // The default form-submit method specified in the Formik Form, submitForm(),
                       // will now be executed if there are no validation errors
                       }} 
    >Submit</Button>                
    ..
    </Form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't manipulate the DOM directly. The link you provided is outdated and has some misleading information. Instead, set attribute `disabled` in JSX. You can simply use Formik's `isSubmitting` value:

```
const submitForm = async (formValues) => {
    const url = '/app/submitAgreement';
    let obj = {'formValues': formValues};
    await axios.post(url, obj);
}

<Formik 
    enableReinitialize
    validationSchema={mySchema} 
    onSubmit={ (values) => {
        submitForm(values); // Calls submitForm() function if there are no errors
    }}
    initialValues={initialFormValues}
>
    {
        ({handleSubmit, handleChange, handleBlur, setFieldValue, setFieldTouched, values, touched, isValid, errors, isSubmitting}) 
        => (

            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> {/* Form starts here */}
            ..
            ..
            <Button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}
    >Submit</Button>                
    ..
    </Form>
```

And if you want the button to stay disabled:

```
const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);

//...

const submitForm = async (formValues) => {
    const url = '/app/submitAgreement';
    let obj = {'formValues': formValues};
    await axios.post(url, obj);
    setIsSubmitted(true);
}

//...
<Button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting || isSubmitted}
```

Comment: Yeah, simply `disabled={isSubmitting}` worked.