# Using debouncer with React event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, underscore.js, dom-events, debouncing

I have an `onchange` event for a field that needs to be debounced, I'm using underscore for that, however when I use the debouncer the event that is passed to the React handler appears to be out of date.

```
<div className='input-field'>
  <input onChange={_.debounce(this.uriChangeHandler.bind(this), 500)} id='source_uri' type='text' name='source_uri' autofocus required />
  <label htmlFor='source_uri'>Website Link</label>
</div>

uriChangeHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let uriField = $(event.target);
    let uri = uriField.val();
    this.setState({
        itemCreateError: null,
        loading: true
    });
    this.loadUriMetaData(uri, uriField);
}
```

I'm getting this error:

Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're calling preventDefault on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is a no-op. See https‍://fb‍.me/react-event-pooling for more information.

Using the `onchange` without the debouncer works fine.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/23123138/870769

Comment: No I tried that with `this.debouncedUriChangeHandler = _.debounce(this.uriChangeHandler, 500);` but get the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in yout case it might help

```
class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {
  uriChangeHandler(target) {
    console.log(target)
  }

  render() {
    var myHandler = _.flowRight(
      _.debounce(this.uriChangeHandler.bind(this), 5e2),
      _.property('target')
    );
    return (      
      <input onChange={myHandler}  />
    );
  }
}

React.render(
  <HelloWorldComponent/>,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jenalulune/1/edit?js,console,output)

Also you can use `_.clone` instead of `_.property('target')` if you want to get the complete event object.

**EDITED**

To prevent React nullifies the event you must call `event.persist()` as stated on [React doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html):

> If you want to access the event properties in an asynchronous way, you should call event.persist() on the event, which will remove the synthetic event from the pool and allow references to the event to be retained by user code.

And hence you could use `e =>  e.persist() || e` instead of `_.clone`
[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/fidofihala/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: That did the trick thanks! Could you explain how? I used the `_.clone` bit instead of `_.property`

Answer (score 17):

I ended up with a solution I saw on github which worked well for me. Basically you wrap the debounce function in a custom function `debounceEventHandler` which will persist the event before returning the debounced function.

```
function debounceEventHandler(...args) {
  const debounced = _.debounce(...args)
  return function(e) {
    e.persist()
    return debounced(e)
  }
}

<Input onChange={debounceEventHandler(this.handleInputChange, 150)}/>
```

This got rid of the synthetic event warning

Comment: Works like a charm! I added this as a global export for easy use.

Answer (score 2):

I went with a combination of [xiaolin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37312154/1678614)'s answer and [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo):

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const handleChange = useMemo(() => {
    const debounced = _.debounce(e => console.log(e.target.value), 1000);
    return e => {
      e.persist();
      return debounced(e);
    };
  }, []);
  return <input onChange={handleChange} />;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think is happening is that the event is being nullified in the time in between the actual event and when your method gets called. Looking at the [`_.debounce` source code](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-83) (and using what we know about debouncing functions) will tell you that your method isn't called until 500 milliseconds until *after* the event fires. So you've got something like this going on:

1. Event fires
2. `_.debounce()` sets a 500 millisecond timeout
3. React nullifies the `event` object
4. The timer fires and calls your event handler
5. You call `event.stopPropagation()` on a nullified event.

I think you have two possible solutions: call `event.stopPropagation()` every time the event fires (outside of the debounce), or don't call it at all.

Side note: this would still be a problem even with native events. By the time your handler actually gets called, the event would have already propagated. React is just doing a better job at warning you that you've done something weird.

Answer (score 0):

```
class HelloWorldComponent extends Component {
    _handleInputSearchChange = (event) => {
        event.persist();
        _.debounce((event) => {
            console.log(event.target.value);
        }, 1000)(event);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <input onChange={this._handleInputSearchChange}  />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: this is so clever

Comment: This isn't a proper solution. Its calling debounce on every onChange event. Solution by @xiaolin is proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is that we want the onChange handler to persist the event first then immediately debounce our event handler, this can be simply achieved with the following code:

```
<input
onChange={_.flowRight(
  _.debounce(this.handleOnChange.bind(this), 300),
  this.persistEvent,
)}
</input>

persistEvent = e => {
  e.persist();
  e.preventDefault();
  return e;
};

handleOnChange = e => {
  console.log('event target', e.target);
  console.log('state', this.state);
  // here you can add you handler code 
}
```