# React Native Prevent Double Tap

Tags: react-native

I have a `TouchableHighlight` wrapping a `Text` block that when tapped, opens a new scene (which I'm using react-native-router-flux).
It's all working fine, except for the fact that if you rapidly tap on the `TouchableHighlight`, the scene can render twice.
I'd like to prevent the user from rapidly being able to tap that button.

What is the best way to accomplish this in Native?  I looked into the Gesture Responder System, but there aren't any examples or anything of the sort, which if you're new, like me, is confusing.

Comment: @efru did any of these answers work for your case?

Answer (score 8):

What you're trying to do is you want to limit your on tap callbacks, so that they will only run ONCE.

This is called **throttling**, and you can use `underscore` for that:
**Here's how:**

```js
_.throttle(
    this.thisWillRunOnce.bind(this),
    200, // no new clicks within 200ms time window
);
```

Here's how my react component looks after all.

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     _.throttle(
        this.onPressThrottledCb.bind(this),
        200, // no new clicks within 200ms time window
    );
  }
  onPressThrottledCb() {
    if (this.props.onPress) {
      this.props.onPress(); // this only runs once per 200 milliseconds
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPressThrottledCb}>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

I hope this helps you.
In case you wanna learn more check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js).

Comment: By doing this way, i couldn't pass params to the function like this `onPress={()=>this.onPressThrottledCb(data)}`

Comment: lodash or underscore's implementation of throttle pass all params to the function automatically

Comment: Now using underscore, and the params do get passed.

Comment: @Maximtoyberman what do you mean it doesn't work? Do you get any errors? Can you debug to see if your callback is being invoked?

Comment: is using `this.onPressThrottledCb.bind(this)` instead of `this.onPressThrottledCb` still necessary if the method is defined as a class property? i.e. `onPressThrottledCb = () => {...}`

Answer (score 4):

The following works by preventing routing to the same route twice:

```js
import { StackNavigator, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const App = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Details: { screen: DetailsScreen },
});

// Prevents double taps navigating twice
const navigateOnce = (getStateForAction) => (action, state) => {
    const { type, routeName } = action;
    return (
        state &&
        type === NavigationActions.NAVIGATE &&
        routeName === state.routes[state.routes.length - 1].routeName
    ) ? state : getStateForAction(action, state);
};
App.router.getStateForAction = navigateOnce(App.router.getStateForAction);
```

Comment: If you use the same screen twice this will fail. For example a quiz app.

Comment: Yes, as the answer states it works by preventing going to the same route twice. If this is not suitable then use a different method. In most cases it is suitable

Comment: In my previous project it was working fine but now it creates a warning: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'routeConfigs[initialRouteName].params'). How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use the new disable-feature introduced for touchable elements in 0.22? I'm thinking something like this:

**Component**

```js
<TouchableHighlight ref = {component => this._touchable = component}
                    onPress={() => this.yourMethod()}/>
```

**Method**

```js
yourMethod() {
    var touchable = this._touchable;
    touchable.disabled = {true};

    //what you actually want your TouchableHighlight to do
}
```

I haven't tried it myself. So I'm not sure if it works.

Comment: how to enable it back, if user comes back from hard coded android back  button.?

Answer (score 2):

I do it like this:

```js
link(link) {
        if(!this.state.disabled) {
            this.setState({disabled: true});
            // go link operation
            this.setState({disabled: false});
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.link('linkName')}>
              <Text>Go link</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could bounce the click at the actual receiver methods, especially if you are dealing with the state for visual effects.

```js
_onRefresh() {    
    if (this.state.refreshing)
      return
    this.setState({refreshing: true});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `react-navigation`, you can supply a `key` property to `navigate` to ensure only one instance is ever added to the stack.

via https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/271

Answer (score 1):

After reading several github threads, SO articles and trying most solutions myself I have come to the following conclusions:

---

1. Providing an additional `key` parameter to do "idempotent pushes" does not work consistently as of now.
   https://github.com/react-navigation/rfcs/issues/16
2. Using `debounce` slows down the UX significantly. The navigation only happens X ms after the user has pushed the button *the last time*. X needs to be large enough to bridge the time where double taps might happen. Which might be anything from 100-600ms really.
3. Using `_.throttle` did not work for me. It saved the throttled function call and executed it after the timer ran out resulting in a delayed double tap.

---

I considered moving to `react-native-navigation` but apparently the issue lies deeper and they experience it too.

So for now I built my own hack that interferes with my code the least:

```js
const preventDoubleTapHack = (component: any, doFunc: Function) => {
  if (!component.wasClickedYet__ULJyRdAvrHZvRrT7) {
    //  eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
    component.wasClickedYet__ULJyRdAvrHZvRrT7 = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      //  eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
      component.wasClickedYet__ULJyRdAvrHZvRrT7 = false;
    }, 700);
    doFunc();
  }
};
```

anywhere, where we navigate instead of

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate('MyRoute');
```

do

```js
preventDoubleTapHack(this, () => this.props.navigation.navigate('MyRoute');
```

Beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do using debounce very simple way

```
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';

componentDidMount() {

       this.yourMethod= debounce(this.yourMethod.bind(this), 500);
  }

 yourMethod=()=> {
    //what you actually want your TouchableHighlight to do
}

<TouchableHighlight  onPress={this.yourMethod}>
 ...
</TouchableHighlight >
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed using this lodash method below,

*Step 1*

```
import { debounce } from 'lodash';
```

*Step 2*

Put this code inside the constructor

```
this.loginClick = debounce(this.loginClick .bind(this), 1000, {
            leading: true,
            trailing: false,
});
```

*Step 3*

Write on your onPress button like this

```
onPress={() => this.props.skipDebounce ? this.props.loginClick : this.loginClick ()}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me as a workaround

```
import React from 'react';
import {TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default SingleClickTouchableOpacity = (props) => {
let buttonClicked = false
return(
    <TouchableOpacity {...props}  onPress={() => {
        if(buttonClicked){
            return
        }
        props.onPress();
        buttonClicked = true 
        setTimeout(() => {
            buttonClicked = false
          }, 1000);
    }}>
        {props.children}
    </TouchableOpacity>
)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did not use disable feature, setTimeout, or installed extra stuff.

This way code is executed without delays. I did not avoid double taps but I assured code to run just once.

I used the returned object from TouchableOpacity described in the docs https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressevent and a state variable to manage timestamps. lastTime is a state variable initialized at 0.

```js
const [lastTime, setLastTime] = useState(0);

...

<TouchableOpacity onPress={async (obj) =>{
    try{
        console.log('Last time: ', obj.nativeEvent.timestamp);
        if ((obj.nativeEvent.timestamp-lastTime)>1500){  
            console.log('First time: ',obj.nativeEvent.timestamp);
            setLastTime(obj.nativeEvent.timestamp);

            //your code
            SplashScreen.show();
            await dispatch(getDetails(item.device));
            await dispatch(getTravels(item.device));
            navigation.navigate("Tab");
            //end of code
        }
        else{
            return;
        }
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }           
}}>
```

I am using an async function to handle dispatches that are actually fetching data, in the end I'm basically navigating to other screen.

Im printing out first and last time between touches. I choose there to exist at least 1500 ms of difference between them, and avoid any parasite double tap.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this bug by creating a module which calls a function only once in the passed interval.

Example: If you wish to navigate from Home -> About And you press the About button twice in say 400 ms.

```js
navigateToAbout = () => dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'About'}))

const pressHandler = callOnce(navigateToAbout,400);
<TouchableOpacity onPress={pressHandler}>
 ...
</TouchableOpacity>
The module will take care that it calls navigateToAbout only once in 400 ms.
```

Here is the link to the NPM module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/call-once-in-interval