# Duplicate click react native

Tags: react-native, onpress

I have a problem when user spam click/tap on a button/TouchableOpacity in react native.

**Ex:** tap to navigate another screen

How can i fix that?

**Function**

```js
onItemPress(title) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate(title.toLowerCase(), { title });
}
```

**Render**

```js
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => this.onItemPress("QuickMenu")}
/>
```

Comment: Use a state variable to control the execution of the `onPress` function. Also, please post your relevant code and attempts to solve your problem. You might want to look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, I'm going to update my code for that.

Comment: Use state variable for handle it?? But when I navigate to another screen, that state is not right at new screen component.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187081/react-native-prevent-double-tap) is an option
Component

```js
<TouchableHighlight ref = {component => this._touchable = component}
                    onPress={() => this.yourMethod()}/>
```

Method

```js
yourMethod() {
    var touchable = this._touchable;
    touchable.disabled = {true};

    //what you actually want your TouchableHighlight to do
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work. 
Thanks for your suggesting. 
But i have a question, if we **disabled** click button for our function, how we handle this button next time click ( not trash click ) ?

Comment: @monkeyluffy I know this is old, but I ended up using the disabled prop on TouchableOpacity. When the function is invoked, I setState to disable the component. Then at the end of the function I use a timeout to reenable the component. This lets me prevent the double tap