# React.js and debouncing onChange event is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have implemented react component on change event like this:

```
NewItem = React.createClass({

  componentWillMount: function() {
    this._searchBoxHandler = debounce(this._searchBoxHandler, 500);
  },

  _searchBoxHandler: function(event) {
    this.context.flux.getActions('order').setOrders(...);
  },

  render: function () {
    ...
    var _self = this;
    return (<TextField onChange={_self._searchBoxHandler} />)      
  })

});
```

I've done this implemention by checking this answer (Good idea section): https://stackoverflow.com/a/28046731/842622

But it's not working. I'm always having 'Cannot read property 'value' of null' from event object.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What happens if you don't debounce the handler? What debounce function are you using? Underscore's?

Comment: btw, you can use `this` in your render without creating a new reference holder in the render function:

`var _self = this;
    return (<TextField onChange={_self._searchBoxHandler} />) `

 ==

`return (<TextField onChange={this._searchBoxHandler} />) `

Comment: @mirat Did this solution help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your context or use a closure to maintain scoping:

```js
NewItem = React.createClass({

  componentWillMount: function() {
    this._searchBoxHandler = debounce(this._searchBoxHandler.bind(this), 500);
  },

  _searchBoxHandler: function(event) {
    this.context.flux.getActions('order').setOrders(...);
  },

  render: function () {
    ...
    var _self = this;
    return (<TextField onChange={_self._searchBoxHandler} />)      
  })

});
```

> A common mistake for new JavaScript programmers is to extract a method from an object, then to later call that function and expect it to use the original object as its this (e.g. by using that method in callback-based code). Without special care however, the original object is usually lost. Creating a bound function from the function, using the original object, neatly solves this problem.. - MDN

Some nice docs on binding and context:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

or you could use a 'fat-arrow' function to access parent class scope:

`debounce((event) => { this._searchBoxHandler(event); }, 500);`

**Note:** I wouldn't overwrite the declared function property in the componentWillMount invocation, instead you could store the debounced instance in another property like `_debouncedSearchBoxHandler`