# handling multi requests in react-native and redux and react-native-maps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm building a react-native app where i use react-native-maps package to show markers on the map with every region by sending request to my server to get some data

```
<MapView
        followUserLocation
        initialRegion={region}
        ref={(ref) => { this.mapRef = ref; }}
        showsUserLocation
        style={styles.map}
        onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange.bind(this)}
/>
```

on RegionChange i send a request to my server

```
onRegionChange(region) {
// send my request to my server
}
```

but the user may make many region change in a very short time , how can i make sure that i'll get the correct response (i.e response related to the last region change ) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this.

**Debounce**

Use debounce for "onRegionChange". This way only the last change will be executed.

More info: [Perform debounce in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js)

**Cancelable promises**

Some Promise libraries provide cancelable promises.

More info: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/cancel.html