# Correct way to lift up state in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm trying to make a Data Grid, it's working by now but I feel like I'm doing it wrong, here are the details:

Each row has multiple input (text, select, button), and we have the ability to delete, insert rows.

Now I have a `GridComponent` that holds all the data as an array of objects. On render it will pass the object to `RowComponent` with a handle to call when the input changes:

```
this.state.data.map((rowdata, index) => 
    <RowComponent 
       key={rowdata.id} 
       rowdata={rowdata} 
       dataindex={index} 
       handleChange={this.handleChange} 
    />
)
```

The problem is when `RowComponent` calls `handleChange`, the `GridComponent` uses the rowindex to update the object. But it's slow and has a little delay while typing.

To solve that problem I then declare a state in `RowComponent` to control the data while typing and only call `handleChange` on the `onBlur` event and it's working very well. But now I have 2 states in the Grid and Row, is it the correct way to do it?

Comment: Both approaches should be fine. How big is the data we're talking about though? Does id change for any reason?

Comment: You are not using anything like flux or redux?

Comment: @HoriaComan : It will not too big just curious because the first approach is slow and the second is duplicate the data. the id is just for key

Comment: @AnthonyKong I've heard about it but it's just a simple app so I haven't look at those two.

Comment: If you have a centralised store then you do not need to worry about keeping two consistent copies of the same state. Save you a lot of trouble down the road.

Comment: @Tubc true, but _how_ big? If we're talking 1000s of elements, that might put enough pressure on React and DOM manipulation that you'd see performance problems. Even if the data is itself small. Wrt the id, it's important for it to stay the same through the lifetime of the component, so React doesn't recreate the components involved on a new render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you [profiled](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/11/16/react-v15.4.0.html#profiling-components-with-chrome-timeline) your code to identify the slowest pieces?

You seem to have done this in an acceptable fashion without using flux. This should be an issue with lots of frequent and preventable renders. Mostly a matter of putting some `shouldComponentUpdate` checks. Unless you [fix](https://blog.lavrton.com/how-to-optimise-rendering-of-a-set-of-elements-in-react-ad01f5b161ae) these, externalizing state will not help (except for libraries which use forceUpdate based approaches, like [MobX](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/blob/2ca68da104223930ec9850c51e1025e591811bed/src/observer.js#L176)).

Also, for inputs you should prefer having either [debounced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js) event handlers, or having a shadow internal state (like you have done), over propogating all changes immediately.

Comment: Thank you, the suggestion to profile the code and use shouldComponentUpdate was really helpful. I understand react more now, really appreciate your answer