# Turn react-select autocomplete on after a few keystrokes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, react-select

Is there a way to only turn the autocomplete on after typing lets say three keystrokes? I am currently using the react library react-select.

Comment: are you also using https://github.com/reactjs/react-autocomplete ?

Comment: @Nevosis No, I am solely using react-select

Answer (score 1):

I would implement to execute asynchronous event after (around) 300ms rather than counting each keystrokes. You can have a look at `debounce` and `persist` in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js)

Comment: Thanks - Well I would like to count the keystrokes. But how can you call the function to trigger the dropdown? Or how can you prevent the dropdown from showing?

Comment: You can try `filterOption`: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select#filtering-options. I think counting the `filter.length` and `return false` should works.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now the dropdown appears after the third keystroke - prior to that it is disabled. But now the search is not working. Do you know why this could be the case?

Comment: Does this (or similar) : `filterOption(option, filter) { return (filter.length % 3) === 0 ? true : false }` solve your issue ?