# React lodash debounce always return null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I want to use lodash within class property but it always return me null for the value. I followed this [Perform debounce in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js) (second answer and solution number 3)

my code:

```
// func
handleSearchInput = debounce(e => {
    console.log(e);
    e.persist();

    console.log(e.target);
}, 500);

// Render
<Input
    type="text"
    onKeyDown={this.handleSearchInput}
    placeholder="Search..."
/>
```

all my `console.log()` always return me null. I want to get my input value.

Any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Yo have to `persist` (or cancel synthetic event re-usage) before calling `debounce`

```
onKeyDown={e => {
  e.persist();
  this.handleSearchInput(e);
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are intending to use a lodash function. You need to import or require lodash first and use the function like this:

```
_.debounce(...)
```

The example you referenced uses a custom function called debounce.

Comment: I've solved it. Fyi I only import function that I use. `import debounce from lodash/debounce`

Comment: How did you install Lodash? I installed it via npm and I can not do like you wrote `import debounce from lodash/debounce` because it says to me 'cannot find module lodash/debounce`

Answer (score 1):

You can persist the synthetic event by using:

```
onClick(event) {
  event.persist();

   setTimeout(() => {
     consoloe.log(event);
   }, 1000);
}
```

OR you can copy the event object:

```
onClick(event) {
 const eventClone = { ...event };

 setTimeout(() => {
     consoloe.log(eventClone);
 }, 1000);
}
```