# Throttling using Lodash in React Native

Tags: react-native, lodash

I am trying to use lodash.throttling to limit the number of onPress calls in a Touchable Highlight, using the below codes, but none works :

```
 <TouchableHighlight
       onPress={throttle(this.onPressHandler,5000,{leading:true, trailing:false})}>

 <TouchableHighlight
       onPress={()=>throttle(this.onPressHandler,5000,{leading:true, trailing:false})}>
```

However, when I put a console.log in the "onPressHandler" function, I see that the function is being called multiple times even if I tap the TouchableHighlight in quick succession.

What am I missing?

Comment: Related to this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working, thanks to Sebastien's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js) question

The answer talks about React.js, but nonetheless the concepts are similar for React Native as well.

I added the below code to the constructor and mapped onPress to onPressHandler directly

```
this.onPressHandler = throttle(this.onPressHandler, 5000, {leading:true, trailing:false});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use the `<Throttle>` component in this package: https://github.com/gmcquistin/react-throttle. It works fine in React Native apps (I'm currently using it in one of mine).

Usage:

```
import { Throttle } from 'react-throttle';

<Throttle time="5000" handler="onPress">
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onPressHandler} />
</Throttle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a `callback` on your `onPress` method so that is not called automatically.

```
<TouchableHighlight
    onPress={() => throttle(this.onPressHandler,5000,{leading:true, trailing:false})}>
```