# debounce on react got e.target.value undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Was trying to debounce an input using lodash's debounce, but below code gave me value of undefined.

```
const { debounce } from 'lodash'

class App extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.handleSearch = debounce(this.handleSearch, 300)
  }

  handleSearch = e => console.log(e.target.value)

  render() {
    return <input onChange={e => this.handleSearch(e)} placeholder="Search" />
  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? Look especially at the section on event pooling for your case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js/28046731

Comment: @kingdaro I followed the thing correctly, compare my code pls, do not simply paste a link

Answer (score 15):

This happens because of event pooling on the React side.

> The SyntheticEvent is pooled. This means that the SyntheticEvent
>   object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the
>   event callback has been invoked. This is for performance reasons. As
>   such, you cannot access the event in an asynchronous way.

```js
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
 var timeout;
 return function() {
  var context = this, args = arguments;
  var later = function() {
   timeout = null;
   if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
  };
  var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
  if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
 };
};

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.handleSearch = debounce(this.handleSearch, 2000);
  }

  handleSearch(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return <input onChange = {
      (event)=>{event.persist(); this.handleSearch(event)}
    }
    placeholder = "Search" / >
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling

Comment: make sense but it doesn't solve my problem. I got the same error.

Comment: e.target.value is `undefined`

Comment: strange did you changed anything?

Comment: @SharonChai onChange handler.  Calling `event.persist()` in the debounced function won't work.

Comment: I'm getting an empty string for e.target.value now.

Comment: @chovy In the sample I have added?

Comment: Confirmed this works. Don't call the non-debounced function directly in `onChange`