# How to perform debounce on onChange react event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem in performing requests to the server when the user types some info in input field. Requests are sent but if the user quickly removes everything from the field, request won't be sent as default but it will send the last letter. So some delay happens.

I need to realize somehow debounce when the user types something quickly and send a request once for 2ms for example

```
<input type="text"
  placeholder="add"
  className='input'
  onChange={(e) => this.search(e.target.value)}
  onKeyDown={this.handleSearchParam}
  value={keyword}
/>
```

function for handling input

```
search(text) {
    this.props.onTextInputAdd(text);
    if (text) {
     this.props.onSearchTypeResult(this.props.tab, text)
    } else {
      this.props.onLoadDefaultInfo(this.props.tab);
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  keyword: state.searchReducers.keyword,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onSearchTypeResult: (tabName, query) => dispatch(actionCreators.loadSearchInfo(tab, tabQuery)),
  onTextInputAdd: keyword => dispatch(actionCreators.addKeyword(keyword)),
});
```

Here is the action:

```
const loadSearchResults = (tabName, query) => axios.get(`testurl?query1=${tabName}&query2=${query}`)

export const loadSearchInfo = (tabName, query) => dispatch => {
  loadSearchResults(tabName, query).then(response => {
    const data = { ...response.data };
    dispatch(updateTabInfo(data));
  });
}

export const updateTabInfo = data => ({
  type: LOAD_TAB_INFO,
  payload: data,
});
```

I tried to use custom debounce but it doesn't work. It fires every time I put text but not on intervals

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perform debounce in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js)

Comment: no it isn't, I checked those but it doesn't the case I have

Comment: You need to create a debounce method on the component instance, then call that method from the onchange. The instance method will make your api call. It is the same.

Comment: so provide me with instruction to my case please. I do not have any idea how to do that using the link you send me. It is the easiest way to send some link and close theme

Comment: I provided you with all the code I write

Answer (score 27):

You can use lodash debounce method like this:

```
search = _.debounce((text) => {
  this.props.onTextInputAdd(text);
  if (text) {
   this.props.onSearchTypeResult(this.props.tab, text)
  } else {
    this.props.onLoadDefaultInfo(this.props.tab);
  }
}, 300);
```

Then you will be able to use it like you already do. The function search will be triggered after 300ms. 2ms will probably be too fast.

```
<input type="text"
  placeholder="add"
  className='input'
  onChange={(e) => this.search(e.target.value)}
  onKeyDown={this.handleSearchParam}
  value={keyword}
/>
```

To use lodash, run `npm install lodash --save` or `yarn add lodash` then import it like this :

```
import _ from "lodash";
```

If you don't want to add lodash only for the debounce function, you can create your own debounce function like this:

```
function debounce(func, wait) {
  let timeout;
  return function() {
    const context = this;
    const args = arguments;
    const later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      func.apply(context, args);
    };
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
  };
};
```

Comment: I know about lodash but I want some custom solution, without connecting such a big library

Comment: You can also import just debounce and not the whole lodash lib... o_o

Comment: I know that but I'm looking for some non library solution

Comment: I added an example of a custom debounce function.

Comment: Vincent, how would you compare your custom `debounce` function to the library implementation?

Comment: The Lodash version has more feature like a maximum wait time, leading and trailing function invoking. It has also been tested on every major browser and it has very good performance on every browser. You are also 100% sure that the Lodash version is bug free.

Comment: Awesome solution! This worked for me perfectly for a project I was working with search and filters.