# Trouble debouncing setState in Context (react-native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, lodash, debouncing

I'm rendering a lot of Text components and saving positions (in order to scroll to them), but I would like to improve performance by "bundling" it by a debounce (and are open for other suggestions that would improve performance).

```
  ...
  import debounce from 'lodash/debounce'
  ...
  class ContextProvider extends Component {
  ....
  setContentPosition = (layout, key) => {
    const contentPos = { ...this.state.contentPos }
    contentPos[key] = layout.nativeEvent.layout.y
    // TODO: make it debounce https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js
    this.setState({ contentPos }, () => console.log('contPos updated'))
  }
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider
        value={{
          setContentPosition: this.setContentPosition,
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

I have tried a couple of different combinations, without luck. Was expecting this to work:

```
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider
        value={{
          setContentPosition: debounce(this.setContentPosition, 200),
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

It throws the following error:

[image: error message]

### Update 01

The following change (for `contentPos[key]`)

```
  setContentPosition = (layout, key) => {
    const contentPos = { ...this.state.contentPos }
    //console.log(layout.nativeEvent)
    contentPos[key] = layout.nativeEvent
    // TODO: make it debounce https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js
    this.setState({ contentPos }, () => {
      console.log('contPos updated')
    })
  }
```

displays this warning instead:

[image]

The position is to be used for scrolling to a text component (when searching) and I have some testing code that scrolls to some `Text` component - works on iOS but not on Android?

Comment: Did you import `debounce` from lodash as such? not `_.debounce`?

Comment: updated my code example to how I imported lodash debounce

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perform debounce in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js)

Comment: @m.a.solano93 I know that it appears to be a duplicate (my code even link to this as a comment), but the answer doesn't work in my instance - think it is because my function takes to params?

Comment: Oh shoot, my bad let me take a closer look then

Comment: Can you console.log out your var `layout.nativeEvent` and see what the result is? Its hung up on the fact that it think `layout.nativeEvent.layout` is null and thus not an `object`.

Comment: first time it logs `null`, then `conPos updated`..

Comment: It now shows a warning `ExceptionsManager.js:71 Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property 'nativeEvent' on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist(). `

Comment: Think it is wierd that I now shows a warning instead of a red error.

Comment: Ah, yeah I think you have a timing / sequence problem.

Comment: @m.a.solano93 do you have any recommendations for me?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: it's an old post. Don't recall finding a solution. Typically when I find one and it's not among the answers I post a solution as an answer

Comment: @Fluous perhaps the react memorize hook would be worth looking into?