# ReactJS delay onChange while typing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need the state to change to maintain the string the user is typing. However I want to delay an action until the user stops typing. But I can't quite place my finger on how to do both.

So When the user stops typing I want an action to be triggered, but not before. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've tried setting an interval to clear out in the `onChange` but its delaying the string being maintained as well.

Comment: The concept of debouncing sounds like it is what you are looking for, there are many packages that support this functionality, and it is not difficult to write yourself 
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-react-and-redux-code-for-improved-performance-4b8d3c19e305?gi=56159788061e

Comment: @BenjaminCharais yes, **debouncing** is correct. It's a weird term though and easy to forget. Once you know the name answers on SO are easy to find: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js/28046731#28046731

Comment: I personally prefer this logrocket article though, it has some nice animations to explain the problem and various solutions: https://blog.logrocket.com/how-and-when-to-debounce-or-throttle-in-react/

Answer (score 116, accepted):

### With React Hooks and Function components

To keep the string the user is typing, use the `useState` hook to store the text the user is typing. Then give that state to the value of the input. Also be sure to use `setState` on the `onChange` event handler of the input, otherwise the input value won't change.

To trigger an action only sometime after the user stops typing, you can use the `useEffect` hook together with `setTimeout`. In this case, we want to trigger `useEffect` when the input value changes, so we'll create a `useEffect` hook and on its dependency array give it the variable with the value of the input. The function given to `useEffect` should use `setTimeout` to trigger an action after the delay time that is desired. Also, the function given to `useEffect` should return a cleanup function that clears the timeout set. This avoids doing actions for input values which are no longer relevant to the user.

Below is a little example of an app that uses the above steps to keep the string the user is typing visible and to show the finished string 500ms after the user stops typing.

```
function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [displayMessage, setDisplayMessage] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeOutId = setTimeout(() => setDisplayMessage(query), 500);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeOutId);
  }, [query]);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={query}
        onChange={event => setQuery(event.target.value)}
      />
      <p>{displayMessage}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: The above idea is good, though I would instead use a library debounce function, not setTimeout, e.g. with Lodash: https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce

Comment: Very nice solution to debouncing in React! I'd like to add that if you forget to set the dependencies of the `useEffect()` method, it will be called whenever the state changes (which could happen if you have multiple `<input />` tags with their own listeners), which could be costly, depending on what you're doing (i.e. validation).

Comment: How about if a user types "google" and then I trigger an api request to fetch some data for query "google" but user types ".com" too right after .6 seconds so technically api will be triggered 2 times, so how I omit result of first api's request result and take the last api request's result as final output specially when it may possible that first api request can be late or early to delivery data than second api request ,

Comment: Amit, this article should answer your question. https://joaoforja.com/blog/5-steps-to-perform-a-search-when-user-stops-typing-using-react-+-hooks-in-a-controlled-component/ I wouldn't do it exactly like that nowadays, but it addresses your concerns.

Comment: @Dmitriy yes - it's good to know the name for this process - **debouncing**. Then you can start searching for *why* this code works, for example this [logrocket blog on debouncing and throttleing](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-and-when-to-debounce-or-throttle-in-react/) explains what we're doing nicely

Answer (score 32):

Sounds you are going to need to use `setTimeout` to start a timer as soon as the user enters text. If the user enters another character, restart the timer. If the user does not type again before the timer completes, it will fire an action that toggles the checkbox:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      text: '',
      checked: false
    };
    this.timer = null;
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {
    if(prevState.text !== this.state.text) {
      this.handleCheck();
    }
  }
  
  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      text: e.target.value
    });
  };
  
  handleCheck = () => {
    // Clears running timer and starts a new one each time the user types
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.toggleCheck();
    }, 1000);
  }
  
  toggleCheck = () => {
    this.setState( prevState => ({ checked: !prevState.checked }));
  }
  
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={this.state.text} onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Start typing..." /><br/>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checked} onChange={this.toggleCheck} />
          Toggle checkbox after user stops typing for 1 second
        </label>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @RamyaVelivala Thanks, very simple solution.

Answer (score 21):

One way to do this would be to have your `onChange` handler execute two functions:

- Function for immediately updating state
- Debounced function

Example code:

```
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';

class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      value: ''
    }

    // Delay action 2 seconds
    this.onChangeDebounced = debounce(this.onChangeDebounced, 2000)
  }

  handleInputChange = (e: Event) => {
    // Immediately update the state
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
    })

    // Execute the debounced onChange method
    this.onChangeDebounced(e)
  }

  onChangeDebounced = (e: Event) => {
    // Delayed logic goes here
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={this.state.value} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. I tried the above answer first but it call the logic number of time to text change. In my case, i am calling an api on change event so i wanted to call it once the user enter the text instead of calling api on each change. Your answer is the perfect solution. Thanks

Comment: the 'debounce' reference is very useful to give this situation a proper name

Answer (score 16):

**With React Hooks and Function components**

```
const [timer, setTimer] = useState(null);

function changeDelay(change) {
    if (timer) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      setTimer(null);
    }
    setTimer(
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(change);
      }, 3000)
    );
}
```

---

In input

```
<input type="text" onChange={(e) => { changeDelay(e.target.value); }} />
```

Answer (score 9):

**With React Hooks - useRef**

```js
const timer = useRef(null)
    
useEffect(() => {
    
    clearTimeout(timer.current)
    timer.current = setTimeout(() => {
     // your logic
    },1000)
    
},[value])
```

Comment: This one is similar to the top-rated one, but the code is much more readable. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

## Call every state update except the first time:

Actually, I have the same issue but a little `setTimeout` could help me with a check `ref` for the first time mount:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from "react";

const Search = () => {
    const filterRef = useRef(); // use ref to call the API call all time except first time
    const [serpQuery, setSerpQuery] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        let delayTimeOutFunction;

        if(!filterRef.current) {
            filterRef.current = true;

        } else { // componentDidMount equivalent
            delayTimeOutFunction = setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('call api: ', serpQuery)
            }, 700); // denounce delay
        }
        return () => clearTimeout(delayTimeOutFunction);
    }, [serpQuery]);

    return (
      <input value={serpQuery} onChange={e => setSerpQuery(e.target.value)} />
    );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can build a custom hook specifically for this purpose and use it just like the useState hook. This is more like an extension of jnforja's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60247456/11785658)

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const useDebounce = (initialValue = "", delay) => {
  const [actualValue, setActualValue] = useState(initialValue);
  const [debounceValue, setDebounceValue] = useState(initialValue);
  useEffect(() => {
    const debounceId = setTimeout(() => setDebounceValue(actualValue), delay);
    return () => clearTimeout(debounceId);
  }, [actualValue, delay]);
  return [debounceValue, setActualValue];
};

export default useDebounce;
```

And use it just like the useState hook with the delay value

```
const [value, setValue] = useDebounce('',1000)
```

You can also check [this](https://karthikraja555.medium.com/react-js-debouncing-or-delaying-value-change-using-custom-hook-1d5fb2e4fe79) article, explaining the implementation if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can debounce on the onChange event  (if the user is typing the onchange event will not execute)

Warning - Keep in mind that creating functions on render is a bad practice.
I did it in order to illustrate the solution.
A more safe solution is to use a class Component that creates the debounced handler on its constructor.

```
class DebouncedInput extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    // Creating the debouncedOnChange to avoid performance issues

    this._debouncedOnChange = _.debounce(
      this.props.onChange, 
      this.props.delay
    );
  }

  render () {
    const { onChange, delay, ...rest } = this.props;
    return (
      <input onChange={this._debouncedOnChange} {..rest} />
    )
  }
}
```

Example below

```js
function DebouncedInput (props) {
  const { onChange, delay = 300, ...rest } = props;
 
  
  return (
    <input 
      {...rest}
      onChange={ _.debounce(onChange, delay)}
    />
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <DebouncedInput 
        type="text"
        placeholder="enter"
        delay={2000}
        onChange={() => console.log('changing')}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not quite what OP is looking for. This will prevent the user from typing too fast, but will not call a function after x seconds of inactivity.

Comment: Ok,  then I wonder why you use a simple debounce function on your answer. weird.

Comment: In this solution you don't use the value of input anyhow. Thus the input is rendered as uncontrolled component which allows you to do the trick. If you make it controlled it will stop working. So the only way to keep using your solution is to work with the input as uncontolled component which isn't recommended in general case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use debounce and throttle of lodash library for delaying to call change handler function, the following code is based on debounce. The same code can be used for the throttle function.
Debounce: delays invoking function until after X milliseconds
Throttle: invokes function at most once per every X milliseconds

Sample code:

```
import React,{useEffect, useState, useMemo} from "react"
import debounce from "lodash.debounce";

export default function App() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const handleChangeSearch = ({ target }) => {
    setSearch(target.value);    
  };
  const debouncedChangeHandler = useMemo(
    () => debounce(handleChangeSearch, 500),
    []
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      debouncedChangeHandler.cancel();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">      
      <label > Search:
      <input sx={{ display: { xs: "none", md: "block" } }}
        onChange={debouncedChangeHandler}
        name="search"
        type="text"
        placeholder="search..."
      />
      </label >
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created npm package for this matter, you can use provided hook to get both immediate and delayed values.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-delayed-search

Answer (score 0):

```
let reqDelay = useRef();

const yourMethod = () => {
  clearTimeout(reqDelay.current);

  reqDelay.current = setTimeout(() => {
    // do your fetch or whatever you want here
  }, 1000)
}
```

This way will prevent to re-render