# How do I resolve a speed dial?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm developing a React native application. I'm using the React native elements library.

I'm using the Search bar. But when I type faster than the keyboard, the search is not working properly.

Example;

I'm writing "Jack," but it's called "Ja".

I hope I can explain my problem. Because my English is not very good. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
handleRefresh = () => {
    this.setState({
      offset: 0,
      maxSize: 10,
      isSearch: false
    }, () => {
        this.loadData();
    });
};

handleLoadMore = () => {
    this.setState({
        maxSize: this.state.maxSize + 10            
    }, () => {
        this.loadData();
    });
};    

loadData = async () => {
    try {
        const { username, token, offset, maxSize } = this.state;

        var credentials = Base64.btoa(username + ':' + token);
        var URL         = `https://crm.example.com/api/v1/Lead?select=name,status&sortBy=createdAt&asc=false&offset=${offset}&maxSize=${maxSize}`;            

        await axios.get(URL, {headers : { 'Espo-Authorization' : credentials }})
        .then(this.dataSuccess.bind(this))
        .catch(this.dataFail.bind(this));
    }catch (error) {
        Alert.alert(
            'Hata',
            'Bir hata meydana geldi. Lütfen yöneticiye başvurunuz.',
            [
                { text: 'Tamam', onPress: () => null }
            ]
        );
    }
};

searchLead = async (text) => {
    try {
        if(text) {
            this.setState({ searchText: text, isSearch: true, isLoading: true });

            const { username, token, maxSize } = this.state;

            var credentials = Base64.btoa(username + ':' + token);
            var URL = "https://crm.example.com/api/v1/Lead?select=name,status&sortBy=createdAt&asc=false&where[0][type]=textFilter&where[0][value]=" + text;

            await axios.get(URL, { headers : { 'Espo-Authorization' : credentials }})
            .then(this.dataSearch.bind(this))
            .catch(this.dataFail.bind(this));
        }else {
            this.setState({ searchText: '' });
            this.handleRefresh();
        }            
    }catch (error) {
        Alert.alert(
            'Hata',
            'Arama başarısız oldu. Lütfen yöneticiniz ile görüşün.',
            [
                { text: 'Tamam', onPress: () => null }
            ]
        );
    }
}

dataSuccess(response) {
    this.setState({ isLoading: false, leadList: response.data.list });
}

dataSearch(response) {
    this.setState({ isLoading: false, searchData: response.data.list });
}

dataFail(error) {
    this.setState({ isLoading: false });

    Alert.alert(
        'Hata',
        'Beklenmedik bir hata oluştu',
        [
            { text: 'Tamam', onPress: () => null }
        ]
    );
}

render() {
    const { isLoading, isRefreshing, searchText, isSearch, leadList, searchData } = this.state;
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <SearchBar 
                placeholder="Bir lead arayın..."
                searchIcon={<Icon
                    name="search"
                    color="white"
                    size={21}
                />}
                onChangeText={this.searchLead.bind(this)}
                onClear={this.handleRefresh.bind(this)}
                onCancel={this.handleRefresh.bind(this)}
                value={searchText}
            />
            { isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator style={styles.loading} size="large" color="orange" /> :
                isSearch ?
                    <ScrollView>
                        <FlatList
                            data={searchData}
                            showLoading={true}
                            renderItem={({item}) =>
                                <ListItem                                    
                                    title={item.name}
                                    subtitle={item.status}
                                    bottomDivider={true}
                                />
                            }
                            keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
                            refreshing={isRefreshing}
                            onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
                        />
                    </ScrollView> :                            
                    <FlatList
                        data={leadList}
                        renderItem={({item}) =>
                            <ListItem                                
                                title={item.name}
                                subtitle={item.status}
                                bottomDivider={true}
                            />
                        }
                        keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
                        refreshing={isRefreshing}
                        onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
                        onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
                        onEndReachedThreshold={0.2}
                    />                            
            }
        </View>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: `when I type faster than the keyboard` that's the part I don't understand, sorry

Comment: Do you mean, the request is sent with 'Ja' instead of 'Jack'? Meaning that you're sending many requests instead of just one request when you stop typing? If yes, then `debounce` is something you should check out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js

Comment: @JaromandaX The last letter I wrote is not detected if I press the keys very quickly when I search in the Search section.

Comment: @Dodiş are you sending a request on every keystroke?

Comment: @VladimirBogomolov Yes, I send a request each time it is pressed. But sometimes the last letter is not detected in fast typing.

Comment: What you'll want is to not send a request on every keystroke, rather wait for the keystrokes to pause (say 500ms) then send a request

Comment: @VladimirBogomolov Please check the code.

Comment: @JaromandaX Can you make an example?

Comment: @Dodiş - there's a bit of code there, it's sometimes easier to ask a question than decode someone elses code :p

Comment: @JaromandaX True :D

Comment: @Dodiş - not really, I don't reactjs very much - that's why I mentioned it in a comment rather than posting an answer - I know exactly how I'd do it in non-reactjs, but that doesn't translate well to reactjs

Comment: Ok @Dodiş - I've given it a shot

Comment: I think your problem lies with the async and the await in your searchlead function. It is not updating the state consistently i believe

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying I don't know reactjs very well, but I think this may work (there may be far better solutions though)

```
searchLead = (() => {
    let req;
    const delayedRequest = callback => {
        const timeout = setTimeout(callback, 500);
        return {
            cancel() {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            }
        };
    };
    return (text) => {
        req && req.cancel();
        req = delayedRequest(async () => {
            try {
                if(text) {
                    this.setState({ searchText: text, isSearch: true, isLoading: true });

                    const { username, token, maxSize } = this.state;

                    var credentials = Base64.btoa(username + ':' + token);
                    var URL = "https://crm.example.com/api/v1/Lead?select=name,status&sortBy=createdAt&asc=false&where[0][type]=textFilter&where[0][value]=" + text;

                    await axios.get(URL, { headers : { 'Espo-Authorization' : credentials }})
                    .then(this.dataSearch.bind(this))
                    .catch(this.dataFail.bind(this));
                } else {
                    this.setState({ searchText: '' });
                    this.handleRefresh();
                }            
            }catch (error) {
                Alert.alert(
                    'Hata',
                    'Arama başarısız oldu. Lütfen yöneticiniz ile görüşün.',
                    [
                        { text: 'Tamam', onPress: () => null }
                    ]
                );
            }
        });
    };
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried, but it is not considered as a function.

Comment: really? how so? it's an IIFE that returns a function, therefore `searchLead` should be a function - are you sure? What is the error message you are getting? nevermind - I found my fault ... hanf on @Dodiş

Comment: Now try it - I forgot to move the `async` @Dodiş

Comment: No function does not recognize. The color of the function name is different.

Comment: sorry, are you getting an error, or are you just basing your comments on the colour of an element in an editor? if you're getting an error, please tell me the error, in full, not just "function does not recognize" - as this is not something a browser or whatever reactjs does would say - there'd be something that makes sense

Comment: Here's the problem **your code** isn't valid anyway - you've omitted something, so babel, with react enabled, chokes on **your code**