# Delay Api call inside componentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs

Need to delay the api update. Beacause when results of the api renders, some of the components delays a little bit and sometimes doesnt print it.

Tried the input user delay, but it was only for typing, so try differents ways to delay the api, but no luck

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
if (prevState.userInput !== this.state.userInput || 
      prevState.page !== this.state.page) {
        if (prevState.userInput !== this.state.userInput)
          this.setState({page: 1});
        if (this.state.userInput === '' && 
        (prevState.userInput !== this.state.userInput)) {
          fetch(API_POPULAR)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => {
            this.setState({
              selection: 'popular?',
              items: json.results, 
              isLoading: false,
              page: 1,
              max_pages: json.total_pages
             });
          });
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want can you please explain a bit more

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. As I understand you actually want to delay the api call. Do you want the same delay after each componentDidUpdate call, or do you want the api call to occur only once for a given amount of time?

Comment: Looks like you're looking for a debounce method. You can use one from lodash and apply it to the function that modifies the input state.

Comment: @remix23 delay after each componentDidUpdate call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perform debounce in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js)

Comment: It seems the OP is not looking for a debounce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to delay the api call after **each** componentDidUpdate call, just wrap your api into the callback of a [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout):

```
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        const delay = 1000; // in ms
        if (
            prevState.userInput !== this.state.userInput || 
            prevState.page !== this.state.page
        ) {
            if (prevState.userInput !== this.state.userInput)
                this.setState({page: 1});
                if (
                    this.state.userInput === '' && 
                    (prevState.userInput !== this.state.userInput)
                ) {
                    setTimeout(
                        () =>
                            fetch(API_POPULAR)
                                .then(response => response.json())
                                .then(json => {
                                    this.setState({
                                        selection: 'popular?',
                                        items: json.results, 
                                        isLoading: false,
                                        page: 1,
                                        max_pages: json.total_pages
                                    });
                                 }),
                         delay
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Be carefull thou as **each** call to componentDidUpdate will result in an asynchronous call to the api delayed by 1 second which may lead to weird behavior.

If you want to allow the user to interact with the UI and fetch something only after a given amount of time without new componentDidUpdate, you will need to use [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout) like so:

```
    if (this.lastCall) clearTimeout(this.lastCall);
    this.lastCall = setTimeout(........);
```

If that's still not what you are looking for, try and look [debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce) and [throttle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/throttle-debounce) as comments above suggested.

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is (Without using `debounce`, that's probably the best for these cases, but it's not a good idea to use it on the `componentDidUpdate`) wrap the whole execution (API call in this case) in a `setTimeout`, this way you could wait for as long as you want to make the call:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
if (prevState.userInput !== this.state.userInput || 
      prevState.page !== this.state.page) {
        if (prevState.userInput !== this.state.userInput)
          this.setState({page: 1});
        if (this.state.userInput === '' && 
        (prevState.userInput !== this.state.userInput)) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            fetch(API_POPULAR)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
              this.setState({
                selection: 'popular?',
                items: json.results, 
                isLoading: false,
                page: 1,
                max_pages: json.total_pages
              });
           });
          }, TIME_TO_WAIT);
}
```