# Set input value with a debounced onChange handler

Tags: react-hooks, debouncing

In my React Hooks app I need to let user type to an input field for 1000ms. When 1000ms expire an API request is sent with the input value.

```
<input type='text' name='name' className='th-input-container__input' onChange={evt => testFunc2(evt.target.value)} />
```

The value is set in `testFunc2(evt.target.value)`:

```
const testFunc2 = useCallback(debounce((text) => setNameFilter(text), 1000), []);
```

Once `nameFilter` is set to a new value `useEffect` issues an API request since `nameFilter` is its dependency.
That way the API is queried with only the resulting user input instead of with each key stroke value but the input stays uncontrolled. When I add the current `nameFilter` value to the input with `value={nameFilter}` user cannot type into the input and the input receives only the last typed character.

How do I get the user typed characters to display in the input?

Comment: Just curious, do you write your own `debounce` function or use lodash's one?

Comment: The one provided by "just-debounce-it".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updated answer:

```js
const debouncedApiCall = useCallback(debounce((text) => {
  getRecordsForPage(1, text, '', '', '', '', 10, {});
}, 1000), [])

useEffect(() => {
  debouncedApiCall(nameFilter);
}, [nameFilter, debouncedApiCall])

<input type='text' value={nameFilter} onChange={evt => setNameFilter(evt.target.value)} />
```

Comment: Here's changes I applied to your solution to make it produce the desired result. Please consider adding those to the solution so I can accept it. `const debouncedApiCall = useCallback(debounce((text) => getRecordsForPage(1, text, '', '', '', '', 10, {}), 1000), []);`.   `useEffect(() => {
 debouncedApiCall(nameFilter);
}, [nameFilter, debouncedApiCall]);`. The `input` element code is as provided in your solution. `getRecordsForPage` is the API call method to send a request.

Comment: Thank you for the nice and timely solution. You missed the `[]` dep array in `useCallback` in `const debouncedApiCall`. Please add it so the code will look correct.

Comment: @ElAnonimo Sorry, I haven't used React for a while and deliberately missed it. Thank you for your correction.

Comment: Please remove `, 1000` from the `getRecordsForPage` arguments. It's the `debounce` timeout value. The `getRecordsForPage` arguments are all listed in the first parens only.