# Using Lodash debounce with React useCallback for input onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, lodash

I'm trying to debounce an `onChange` event when a user type in a input field.

I'm referencing these threads:

- [How can I perform a debounce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js)
- [Set input value with a debounced onChange handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59358092/set-input-value-with-a-debounced-onchange-handler)

I have the following snippet where I try to replicate the solutions provided in the threads above:

```
const handler = useCallback(debounce(setSearchQuery(value), 500), []);

useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener('keydown', handleDocumentKeyDown);
  handler(value);
  return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleDocumentKeyDown);
}, [isOpen, handleDocumentKeyDown, handler, value]);

// ...

const handleChange = (event) => {
  setValue(event.target.value);
};
```

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: handler is not a function

How can I debounce `setSerachQuery()` for `500ms` while the user is typing in the input field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue in your case is that instead of passing a function to debounce, you are invoking it directly. You can use arrow function within debounce like

```
const handler = useCallback(debounce(() => setSearchQuery(value), 500), []);
```

Full code

```
const handler = useCallback(debounce(() => setSearchQuery(value), 500), []); // arrow function here

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleDocumentKeyDown);
    handler(value);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleDocumentKeyDown);
  }, [isOpen, handleDocumentKeyDown, handler, value]);

  ...

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };
```

Comment: this gives me the lint error `React Hook useCallback received a function whose dependencies are unknown. Pass an inline function instead.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Comment: you could pass setSearchQuery as a dependency to useCallback but since the function doesn't change, you can disable the eslint warning too. Check [this post for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook/55854902#55854902)

Comment: You cannot assume the function doesn't change and also disabling eslint warnings is a bad practice if you're working in a team, as you don't want newbie devs to copy this practice, bypassing eslint warning the second they get into difficulties. So, I suggest, spending as much time as possible solving the issues

Answer (score 4):

Not pretty at all, but the only way I've managed to do it without dependency problems is:

```
  const debouncer = useRef(debounce((over: Over | null) => {
    console.log(over);
  }, 100));

  const onOver = useCallback((over: Over | null) => {
    debouncer.current(over);
  }, [debouncer]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `useMemo()` instead, should be something like this:

```
const handler = useMemo(() => debounce(
  (value) => setSearchQuery(value),
  500,
), []);
```

Source:

- https://kyleshevlin.com/debounce-and-throttle-callbacks-with-react-hooks/
- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19240#issuecomment-652945246

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using a `ref` here. The reasoning is, react demands we use an inline function in `useCallback`, so `debounce` just cannot fit in the `useCallback` statement. So we need to sync the debounced version with `useCallback`'s result. Which leads to a `useEffect`.

(In my case I'm using redux-toolkit so `dispatch` is the dependency, and I need to debounce the request sender triggered by user input.)

```js
const debouncedFetcherRef = useRef((_input: string) => {});

const fetcher = useCallback(
  (input: string) => {
    dispatch(sendRequest({ search: input }))
  },
  [dispatch]
);

useEffect(() => {
  debouncedFetcherRef.current = debounce(fetcher, 500);
}, [fetcher]);

<Input onInput={event => {
  debouncedFetcherRef.current(event.target.value);
}}/>
```