# ReactJS: debounce a function that has as an argument a state value; what's the best way to do it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debouncing, usecallback

I already visited this link and tried to follow some examples: [Perform debounce in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js)

**A bit of context**: I'm building a search box that I want to deploy on NPM. Each time the user types, a prop function `onSearch` is called. This to allow the programmers to fetch new data if they want.

**The problem:** each character typed will trigger onSearch, but that's not optimal, so I want to debounce that.

I wanted to do as one of the posts suggests:

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import { debounce } from "lodash";

const handler = useCallback(debounce(someFunction, 2000), []);

const onChange = (event) => {
    // perform any event related action here

    handler();
 };
```

My problem is that I need to pass an argument to "someFunction", and that argument is a state (a string):

```
const [searchString, setSearchString] = React.useState("");
```

After various attempts I finally found a solution. Remembering how I debounced the window resize event in the past, I followed more or less the same pattern. I did it by attaching an event listener to the window object and by adding a property to the event when dispatching it. It works, but is it a good solution? Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
  React.useEffect( ()=> {

    // This will contain the keyword searched when the event is dispatched (the value is stored in event.keyword)
    // the only function dispatching the event is handleSetSearchString
    // It's declared at this level so that it can be accessed from debounceDispatchToParent
    let keyword = "";

    // This function contains the onSearch function that will be debounced, inputDebounce is 200ms
    const debounceDispatchToParent = debounce(() =>
      onSearch(keyword,  isCached("search-keyword-" + keyword)), inputDebounce);

    // This function sets the keyword and calls debounceDispatchToParent
    const eventListenerFunction = (e) => {
      // the event has a property attached that contains the keyword
      // store that value in keyword
      keyword = e.keyword;
      // call the function that will debounce onSearch
      debounceDispatchToParent();
    }

    // Add the listener to the window object
    window.addEventListener("dispatchToParent", eventListenerFunction, false);

    // Clean up
    return ()=> window.removeEventListener("dispacthToParent", eventListenerFunction);
  }, []);
```

Then everytime the user types I call handleSetSearchString:

```
  const handleSetSearchString = keyword => {

    keyword = keyword.toLowerCase();
    // If the string is longer than the minimum characters required to trigger a filter/search
    if (keyword.length > minChars) {
      // Here I create the event that contains the keyword
      const event = new Event("dispatchToParent");
      event.keyword = keyword;
      window.dispatchEvent(event);

    } else if (keyword.length === 0) {
      // If the string is empty clear the results
      setFilteredItems([]);
    }
    setSearchString(keyword);

  };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since both `debounce` and `useCallback` return a function you could just pass it directly.

```
const handler = useCallback(debounce(someFunction, 2000), []);

const onChange = (event) => {
   // perform any event related action here

   handler(argument1, argument2, ...args);
};
```