# How we can call microsoft Search API with POST in React App

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to call MS Graph Search API in react app, I registered the app with sites.read.all with delegated permissions.
The filter should be from SharePoint list data.

```
code
https://graph.microsoft.com/v2.0/search/query
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "listItem"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "contoso"
         }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFIAK there is no code or searching option for using Search API in MS graph, you can refer to this similar question:[API based search using React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61080751/api-based-search-using-react)

Or raise a feature request for the same in here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am working for MS Search API with filter as per metadata .