# Is it possible to detect a state change during render in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This probably seems like an odd question, but what I'm trying to do is create a simple search field in React. I don't want to make an API call every time the search field is changed, but only if a certain time e.g 500ms has passed since the last state change to ensure that the user isn't typing anymore.

I wanted to do this using the setTimeout function, but I can't find a way to find out during rendering if a state change has been made or something has been added on top of the call stack.

So is there a way to check if there is another render scheduled during rendering?

Something like this:

```
export default function(){
  setTimeout(() => {CHECK IF THERE'S BEEN A STATE CHANGE, IF NOT FETCH API}, 500)
}
```

Comment: The technique you're looking for is called debouncing. Try this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js

Comment: @CameronLittle Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept used to achieve what you want is called debouncing. You can choose to implement a custom debounce function yourself or even use it from a libray.

Considering the fact that you use a functional component and assuming that you use hooks, you can implement the above like

```
const debounce = (fn, delay) => {
   let timer = null;
   return function(...args) {
       // The function is called again but there isn't enough delay
       // between two calls so cancel the previous call
       if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
       // set up a function call timer again
       timer = setTimeout(() => {
           fn.apply(this, args)
       }, delay);

   }
}
```

and you can use it in your component like

```
const Input = () => {
    const handleChange = (e) => {
       // make an api call here
     }
    const debouncedHandleChange = useCallback(debounce(handleChange, 1000), []);
    return (
       <input type="text" onChange={debouncedHandleChange} />
    )

}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot. Hadn't heard of this concept before.