# react leaflet onMoveEnd cause error : "Maximum update depth exceeded"

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

I have the following code to perform a state update every time the map move.

```
 function updateMap() {
    const b = mapRef.current.leafletElement.getBounds()
    const zoomm = mapRef.current.leafletElement.getZoom()
    const initBound = [b.getSouthWest().lng, b.getSouthWest().lat, b.getNorthEast().lng, b.getNorthEast().lat]

    setZoom(zoomm)
    setBound(initBound)
  }
```

bellow is the Map Component, I also tried the `onMoveEnd` event

```
<Map onViewportChanged={updateMap}/>
```

it is working fine for couple of moves however sometime especially if I kept moving the map it freezes and I get the `Maximum update depth exceeded` error .

can someone please explain the reason, is it a bug on react Leaflet or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to run this at the END of your move, not DURING your move.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because you're updating state on every move, and in react you can update the state just for a limited number of times to prevent infinite loops for example.

One way to solve the problem is to debounce the updateMap method.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js) to look at different ways of performing the debouncing.

I hope this helps!