# useEffect side effect on submit of form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

Let's say I have a form with some user input fields and a submit button in the header that dispatches a couple of actions when pressed. I use a function called `calculate`, which takes a user input stored in `number` and updates a state variable `result`, which I would like to pass to `submitFunction` after pressing a submit header button. I am trying to achieve this with `useEffect`, but for some reason `result` is not being updated in time.

For example, if I enter 99 in the text input field, `result` is sent to the `submitHandler` as 90 instead of 990, i.e. one of the digits from the text input is being left off. Can someone tell me how to modify `useEffect` or my function calls so that `number` will be updated in time and the correct value of `result` is passed to `submitHandler`?

```
const ExampleScreen = props => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
    const [result, setResult] = useState(0);

    const calculate = (n) => {
        setResult(n * 10);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        calculate(number); // something not working here!
    })

    const submitHandler = useCallback(() => {
        dispatch(updateList(result));
        dispatch(updateTotal(result));
    }, [dispatch, result]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        props.navigation.setParams({submit: submitHandler});
    }, [submitHandler]);

    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput
                keyboardType='numeric'
                value={number}
                onChangeText={(val) => setNumber(val)}
            />
        </View>
    );
};

ExampleScreen.navigationOptions = navData => {
    const submitFunction = navData.navigation.getParam('submit');
    return {
        headerRight: () => <HeaderButtons>
            <Item 
                title='Submit'
                iconName='md-checkmark'
                onPress={submitFunction}
            />
        </HeaderButtons>
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Restrict the update of `result` only for change in `number` value not for every render (if you don't pass **second argument** to **useEffect** it updates on every render)

```js
useEffect(() => {
  calculate(number); // something not working here!
}, [number]) // Add number as hook dependency
```

Or

If you are not using `calculate` function anywhere else

```
useEffect(() => {
  setResult(number * 10);
}, [number])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because when entering 99, actually there are 2 onChangeText events, the first 9 you entered, you will get 90 as the result from submitHandler, and 990 for the second 9.

I think you may need a **[debounce function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js)** for the input component.