# Get data from API returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, database, react-native, api, axios

```
export class Diet extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
      searchValue: "",
    };
  }
  updateSearch = (value) => {
    this.setState({ searchValue: value });
    if (value.trim() !== "") {
      axios
        .get(
          `https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/v2/parser?ingr=${value}&app_id=2626c70d&app_key=0c0f87ae4e5437621363ecf8e7ea80ae`
        )
        .then((res) => {
          this.setState({ data: console.log(res.data.hints) });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.response.data);
        });
    }
  };

return (
     <SearchBar
        placeholder="Search Food..."
        onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
        value={searchValue}
      />

     <FlatList
              style={{ paddingTop: hp("2%") }}
              data={this.state.data.map((item) => item.food)}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <List>
                  <ListItem>
                    <Left>
                      <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text>{item.label}</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    </Left>
                    <Right>
                      <Icon
                        name="arrow-forward"
                        style={{ fontSize: 25, color: "red" }}
                      />
                    </Right>
                  </ListItem>
                </List>
              )}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.foodId}
            />
```

Hi everyone, I'm trying to get data from the API of Edamam, I'm using a `SearchBar` to get the value the user is typing and show the list of the `label` of foods in the `FlatList` below, the URL works fine, when I run the code and I start typing the `console.log` returns 'undefined'.

Link to documentation: https://developer.edamam.com/food-database-api-docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.edamam.com/food-database-api-docs), it looks like `res.data.parsed` returns an array. You should use `res.data.parsed[0].food` to get access to the parsed food item and `res.data.hints` to access the list of foods. I'm guessing you want to display the latter.

```
axios
  .get(
    `https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/v2/parser?ingr=${value}&app_id=2626c70d&app_key=0c0f87ae4e5437621363ecf8e7ea80ae`
  )
  .then((res) => {
    this.setState({ data: res.data.hints })
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.response.data)
  })
```

```
<FlatList
  style={{ paddingTop: hp('2%') }}
  data={this.state.data.map((item) => item.food)}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    // ...
  )}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.foodId}
/>
```

The `renderItem` function renders a list for every item which doesn't look right. You probably want to render a `ListItem` instead.

And you might want to debounce the input change handler. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js) answer for more information.

Comment: I ran your code, and the console returned the array correctly, but the app shows the following error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.data.map')`

Comment: @PiersalvoMigliore Looks like you're not setting the state properly. You should use `this.setState({ data: res.data.hints })`.

Comment: @PiersalvoMigliore As I mentioned in my previous comment, you're not setting the state right. `console.log` returns `undefined`. Refer to my previous comment or the answer above.

Comment: @PiersalvoMigliore Btw, please add your edits to a separate section in the question to make sure your original question and the initial version of the code remain visible (not everyone has the patience to dig into the revision history). With your current edits, the description and the code don't match at all.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, by the way it shows another error: `Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `food_bmyxrshbfao9s1amjrvhoauob6mo`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.` is the problem the keyExtractor?

Comment: @PiersalvoMigliore Interesting. Looks like the API returns duplicate food items (items with the same `foodId` value). You could remove the duplicates before rendering the items.