# real time populate search with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Right now my search function is I have to click the search icon to make it appear the result so I want to change that to real-time search. When I type the name in input it will auto-starting appear the user card for me

Here is my following code:

```
const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSearchQuery(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const res = await axios.get(
      `/api/v1/search/users/invite/${searchQuery}/${teamId}`
    );
    setInvitees(res.data[0]);
    setShowInvitees(!showInvitees);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchQuery === "") {
      setInvitees([]);
    }
  }, [searchQuery]);

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="invitees-search">
            <Button
              className="input invitees--search-icon"
              style={{ color: "white", backgroundColor: "#00B790" }}
              type="submit"
            >
              <SearchIcon />
            </Button>
            <input
              className="invitees--search_input"
              type="text"
              name="name"
              onChange={handleChange}
              placeholder="Name"
              aria-label="Search bar"
              pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+"
              required
            />
          </div>
        </form>
```

How can I make it auto-populate when my search query length is >= 2 letters?

Comment: Don't forget to optimize your code by using `debounce` like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so with the help of `useEffect`

**Explanation:**

> 1. I renamed your `handleSubmit` function to `getInvitees`
> 2. Calling `getInvitees` function when `searchQuery` length is more than or equal to 2

### Solution

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(searchQuery === "") {
      setInvitees([]);
   }    
   if((searchQuery||'').length >= 2) {
      getInvitees();
   }    
}, [searchQuery]);

const getInvitees = async () => { // renamed handleSubmit function to getInvitees
   const res = await axios.get(`/api/v1/search/users/invite/${searchQuery}/${teamId}`);
   setInvitees(res.data[0]);
   setShowInvitees(!showInvitees);
};
```

Comment: I'm getting error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined`

Comment: @NhanNguyen Remove that line, now no need of that. I updated the answer too.

Comment: Can I ask! Why do we use `useEffect`?

Comment: You can also do the same code in handleChange but then you have to pass e.target.value to getInvitees function. This is because of the asynchronous nature of seState ( setSearchQuery(e.target.value) ).

Comment: You can check this by console.log(searchQuery) in handleChange method. There, you will get old value when you type in. But inside useEffect callback you will get latest updated value always.

Comment: How can I optimize my code with debounce ?

Comment: @NhanNguyen You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-debounce

Comment: Can you help me with this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67624257/how-to-use-usedebounce-for-search-function-in-react/67624428#67624428