# Run the action only when the selected text is stable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, monaco-editor

I would like to set a timer for the `action` function. The rule is: **when the selected text does not change for 3 seconds, we run the function `action` with the selected text**.

I tried the following code in the playground https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html, it did not work. When I changed the selected text very quickly, their actions were not cancelled.

Could anyone help?

```
const editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
    value: '1+2+3+4+5+6+7',
    language: 'javascript'
});

function action(x) {
    console.log("action", x)
}

let myTimeout
editor.onDidChangeCursorSelection((e) => {
    clearTimeout(myTimeout)
    console.log("cleared", myTimeout)
    let selectedText = editor.getModel().getValueInRange(editor.getSelection())
    if (selectedText != "") { // if we are already in this event, the selected text must change
        myTimeout = setTimeout(action(selectedText), 3000);
        console.log("set", myTimeout, selectedText)
    } 
})
```

**Edit 1:** My component is a class component, so I cannot use hook calls.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Perform debounce in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js)

Comment: The link is useful, but I would like a precise solution for my precise request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lodash`'s `debounce` to achieve the effect you want. And use `useCallback` to make sure you get the same instance of function. I think an implementation like this might work:

```js
import _ from 'lodash';

...

const debouncedAction = _.debounce(action, 3000).bind(this);

editor.onDidChangeCursorSelection((e) => {
    let selectedText = editor.getModel().getValueInRange(editor.getSelection())
    if (selectedText != "") { // if we are already in this event, the selected text must change
        debouncedAction(selectedText);
    } 
})
```

I used [this](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-throttle-debounce/) as a reference.

Comment: Thank you for this. But my component is a class; I cannot use hook call. I will add it to the OP.

Comment: It has been a while since the last time I used class component, but the updated answer should essentially do the same thing without using `useCallback`.

Comment: It works, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` takes function as input, while you have called it. I think the following code works well.

```js
const editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
    value: '1+2+3+4+5+6+7',
    language: 'javascript'
});

function action(x) {
    console.log("action", x)
}

let myTimeout
editor.onDidChangeCursorSelection((e) => {
    clearTimeout(myTimeout)
     let selectedText = editor.getModel().getValueInRange(editor.getSelection())
    if (selectedText != "") {
        // "action" is called inside a function
        myTimeout = setTimeout(() => action(selectedText), 3000);
    } 
})
```

Comment: It does not work well. It always prints `action 1+2+3+4+5+6+7`.

Comment: That's right, I corrected it. @SoftTimur

Comment: It's working now, thank you.