# how to define string for .toLowerCase for filter search with multiple search items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, filter

I am new at React and am having trouble defining some things. My goal is to get a filter search working and filter through a JSON via API. The console shows that what I type in is acknowledged, but I keep getting undefined errors, even though I thought they were defined.

Additionally, as this is a search that can find either first or last names, how can I set the keyword to look through two separate items, i.e. `data.students[0].firstName` and `data.students[0].lastName` at once and properly send filtered results as you type?

Here's what I have:

```
const USERS = "https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students";
export default function FilterSearch() {
  const [name, setName] = useState(" ");
  const [foundUsers, setFoundUsers] = useState([]);

  const filter = (keyword) => {
    setName(keyword); 
    if (!keyword || keyword !== " ") {
      setFoundUsers([]); 
    }
    axios.get(USERS).then((listStudents) => {
      console.log(listStudents);
      const results = listStudents.data.students.filter((keyword) => {
        return name.toLowerCase(keyword).startsWith(keyword.toLowerCase());
      });
      setFoundUsers(results);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form>
        <input
          type="search"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => {
            filter(e.target.value);
          }}
          className="input"
          placeholder="Filter"
        />
        ;
      </form>

      <div className="user-list">
        {foundUsers && foundUsers.length > 0 ? (
          foundUsers.map((name) => <StudentInfo name={name} />)
        ) : (
          <h1>No results found!</h1>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This ideally would feed search results into this StudentInfo component:

```
export default function StudentInfo({ info }) {
  return (
    <div className="StudentInfo">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-3">
          <img
            src={info.pic}
            alt={info.firstName}
            width={200}
            className="img-fluid pics"
          />
          <hr />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-9">
          <h1 className="name">
            {info.firstName} {info.lastName}
          </h1>
          <h2>Email: {info.email}</h2>
          <h2>Company: {info.company}</h2>
          <h2>Skill: {info.skill}</h2>
          <h2>Average: {info.grades[0]}</h2>
          <hr />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The list of students to choose from is already laid out; it just needs to be filtered via the search bar to specify a particular entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to apply a search bar for the list of users. But what if there is no search applied. Don't you need to show the list of available?

Whenever the search is typing, you are firing an API call and filtering the data from it. I would suggest you apply to [debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js) for this. And coming to your error.

```
const results = listStudents.data.students.filter((keyword) => {
  return name.toLowerCase(keyword).startsWith(keyword.toLowerCase());
});
```

In the above code, `keyword` is a student object and you can't apply `toLowerCase()` on the object. You can do `keyword?.name(whatever the field)` and apply `toLowerCase()`.

I have made a simple sandbox with [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) hook and applied filtering to the list of students. Have a look at this and modify your code based on your requirements.

[image: Edit eager-oskar-1h3p7d]

Comment: Thank you. Your sandbox helped me figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure I understand right, you want to filter `USERS` and set that to `foundUsers`? If that's the case...

```
const filter = (keyword) => {

    if (!keyword || keyword !== " ") {
      setFoundUsers([]); 
    }
    axios.get(USERS).then((listStudents) => {
      console.log(listStudents);
      const results = listStudents.data.students.filter((keyword) => {
        return name.toLowerCase(keyword).startsWith(keyword.toLowerCase());
      });
      const results = listStudents.data.students.filter((singleValueFromStudentArray, index, arrayItSelf) => {
      //This is a regex way to do it, but do what you like.
      let regex = new Regex(keyword, "gi") \\ gi=global meaning whole word, caseInsensitive
      // Filter just returns a true of false value, and then results is only the true results. This will match every singleValueFromStudentArray that has every character in keyword. If keyword is S, sam, and steve will be true. If it's sa, steve will be false, and if keyword is sm, sam would also be true.
      return regex.test(singleValueFromStudentArray)
      })
      setFoundUsers(results);
    });
/// Set the new value *after* you've used the current one
    setName(keyword); 
  };
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ) on top of providing more or less scarcly-explained code-only-answer. For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."