# How to implement debounce in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement `debounce` on search. 
 The idea is to send a request to the api once user stopped typing.
I have a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/debaunce-errmsl?file=/src/App.js), which works fine. You can see there that typed value will be printed on the screen once finished typing
Now I am trying to implement the same feature on the same input with search functionality, but it doesn't work and throws an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
```

Here is the component and the [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-water-8txnzg?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import data from "./MOCK_DATA.json";
function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const debounce = (func, delay) => {
    let timer;
    return (...arg) => {
      if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        func(...arg);
      }, delay);
    };
  };

  const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  };

  const debouncedOnChangeHandler = debounce(onChangeHandler, 1000);

  const filteredData = data.filter((el) =>
    el.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase())
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>Search</div>
      <input
        value={name}
        onChange={debouncedOnChangeHandler} //debouncedOnChangeHandler doesn't work because value is asynchronous
        //onChange={onChangeHandler} //this works fine without debounce function
        type="text"
        placeholder="search"
      />
      {filteredData &&
        filteredData.map((el) => <div key={el.id}>{el.first_name}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of implementing it on your own, I recommend using `useDebounce` from the `react-use` package: https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useDebounce.md

Comment: @marcobiedermann thanks for the advice. I appreciate it. But before moving to packages, I want to understand how it works and the use them.

Comment: @Greg, Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-mountain-ec3q9j . Make the debounce handler like `const debouncedOnChangeHandler = debounce(onChangeHandler, 1000);` and remove `value={name}` in the input.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan wait what did you change? It works fine

Comment: @ManirajMurugan ok I see, you removed value field

Comment: @ManirajMurugan can you explain please, why it was not working and why it started to work after removing value from input?

Comment: Also could you post your answer so that I can mark as a correct answer?

Comment: @Greg, Posted as answer and you need to make two changes here as described below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform debounce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/how-to-perform-debounce)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some changes which you need to make,

**First** debouncedOnChangeHandler variable holds the function like,

```
   const debouncedOnChangeHandler = (e) => {
    debounce(onChangeHandler(e), 1000);
   };
```

But whereas this doesn't pass the `onChangeHandler` as expected argument for `debounce` method.

So you need to just passdown the debounce function along with required parameters like,

```
const debouncedOnChangeHandler = debounce(onChangeHandler, 1000);
```

**Second:** You need to remove `value={name}` which is not needed in this context.

**Forked Codesanbox:**

[image: Edit mutable-mountain-ec3q9j]