# What is the best way to add a debounce effect on field in react/react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, debouncing

I am trying to add a debounce effect on my useEffect as of right now, as soon as value in input changes it start to call the function inside it.

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (inputValue.length > 0) {
       fn();
   }
}, [inputValue]);
```

Any suggestion how I can improve or implement a debounce effect here.

Comment: `debounce(fn)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform debounce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/how-to-perform-debounce)

Comment: No, it does not.
I am trying to find a way to create a hook which can be used like a useEffect (let's say useDebounceEffect) for debouncing.

Comment: https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/ and https://github.com/xnimorz/use-debounce may be of help

Comment: Great, it works. Thank you! @evolutionxbox
I will write my own hook using this idea https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple `useDebounceEffect`:

```
const useDebounceEffect = (fnc, deps, delay) => {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    clearTimeout(ref.current);
    ref.current = setTimeout(() => {
      fnc();
      clearTimeout(ref.current);
    }, delay);
  }, [...deps, fnc, delay]);
};
```

Make use of a `ref` to keep the timer id.
Pass the delay as an argument.

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-montalcini-h7tps9?file=/src/App.js:77-332)