# Format number as you type when Android keyboard not showing decimal

Tags: javascript, html

**Background**
When using the default Android browser (internet) on the Samsung Note, and maybe other Andriod device, when editing input field using the type "numeric" , the keyboard, which is a number pad, does not have a decimal button on it!

```
<input id="x" type="number" value="" />
```

[image]

I noticed the Bank of America Andriod app does not have a decimal on the number pad. This is how they handle it.

1. click on field
2. type first number "1" and field display 0.01
3. type second number "2" and field display 0.12
4. type third number "3" and field display 1.23
5. type forth number "4" and field display 12.34

I would like to mimic this functionality on my web site that will be used for from mobile devices.

This [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ceJcn/7/) from [mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan) is very close. I want to show two places decimal all the time and this solution shows does not until the forth character is press:

```
$("#txtamt").keyup(function(obj, evt) {
var event = (window.event) ? window.event : evt;

    //ignore arrow keys so that user can move curser 
    switch(event.keyCode)
    {
        case 37:
        case 38:
        case 39:
        case 40:
            return;
        default:
            break;
    }                

    var str = document.getElementById("txtamt");
    str.value = str.value.replace(".", "");

    if (str.value.length == 3) {
        var val = parseFloat(str.value);
        var val1 = (val / 10).toFixed(1);
        str.value = val1;
    }
    else if (str.value.length > 3) {
        var val = parseFloat(str.value);
        var val1 = (val / 100).toFixed(2);
        str.value = val1;
    }
```

});

One obvious solution is just to change the input type and have the standard full keyboard display.

Comment: Have you tried to do anything yourself?

Comment: i don understand how if user is trying to give 123 after he enters 1 do u want it to become 0.01 or he enters the complete val n then clicks some button

Comment: Do you really want to change the contents of the input as the user types? Image I want to type '12' - after hitting '1' the contents will become 0.01, then when I hit '2' it will become 0.00012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution mimics the functionality and use case described in the question. I added the type and value property to the input field.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ceJcn/30/)

```
<input id="txtamt" maxlength="8" type=numberic value="0.00" />
```

Modified the code to format the input string of any length (removed the condition statements).

```
$("#txtamt").keyup(function (obj, evt) {
var event = (window.event) ? window.event : evt;

//ignore arrow keys so that user can move curser 
switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 37:
    case 38:
    case 39:
    case 40:
        return;
    default:
        break;
}

var str = document.getElementById("txtamt");
str.value = str.value.replace(".", "");

var val = parseFloat(str.value);
var val1 = (val / 100).toFixed(2);
str.value = val1;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you using simple javascript

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="number" onchange="formatNumber()"/>
```

JS

```
function formatNumber(){
  var number = document.getElementById('number').value;
  document.getElementById('number').value = ((+number)/100).toFixed(2);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/C7JJM/34/)

But this will work when you leave the textbox.

Comment: @Nivedita then it will be difficult to get the expected, you can try changing `keypress` to `keyup` in demo.

Comment: yes u r right keyup won't work, but don't you think **this will work when u leave the textbox** makes it less user friendly ..

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit of research.

You can write a smart code which first checks if the user has stopped entering value and then converts the input into desired form, like this:

HTML:

```
  <input type="text" id="num" />
```

JS code:

```
var timeoutReference;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input#num').keypress(function() {
        var _this = $(this); 

        if (timeoutReference) clearTimeout(timeoutReference);
        timeoutReference = setTimeout(function() {
            number = document.getElementById('num').value;

      document.getElementById('num').value = ((+number)/100).toFixed(2);
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Live [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nive00/xVBMW/209/)

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042193/how-to-trigger-an-event-in-input-text-after-i-stop-typing-writting) SO answer for more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

try this, [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qhnreofv/) here

```
$('#test').change(function() {
    var testValue = parseInt($('#test').val());

    $('#test').val((testValue/100));
});
```

Comment: This doesn't deal with decimal places

Comment: but question isn't states that input will be decimal numbers. What OP wants when he input is decimal, Can you please help me @joews

Comment: @Barry, can you please check fiddle and revert if you need any further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this JSFiddle demo. This will demonstrate the javascript side of what you want to know:

[Click here to visit the JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ProgrammerKid/0cr8ck1q/5/)

They key to getting your magical number is this one line:

```
var output = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputID").value)*.01;
document.write(output);
```