# Using Google Translate for multilingual textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-translate, translate

I am able to successfully to do that with page refresh when i select a language from dropdown. but when i want to the same without refresh with ajax.it gives error.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    google.load("elements", "1", {
        packages: "transliteration"
    });
</script>    

<select name="langpair" style="height:32px; padding:0;" id="langpair" size="1">
    <option value="ENGLISH">ENGLISH</option>
    <option value="AMHARIC" >AMHARIC</option>
    <option value="HINDI">HINDI</option>
</select>
<br/>
<hr>
<textarea class="form-control" maxlength="160" id="message" name="message" rows="3" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
<br/>
    <script>
           $("#langpair").change(function() {
        var data = this.value;
var options = {
                    sourceLanguage: google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
                    destinationLanguage: [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode[data]],
                    shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
                    transliterationEnabled: true
                };

                //console.log(options);

                var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);
                control.makeTransliteratable(['message']);
    });
    </script>
```

Console.log(c) gives `[[object Object].HINDI]`.

changelanguage.php return language name like HINDI as `data`

Check dis [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEbgpX) link.

please help.
Thanks

Comment: Try changing `var c = '[' + a + '.' + b + ']';` to `var c = [ a , b ];`. But to better understand, what exactly value do you expect to be logged by `console.log(c);`?

Comment: when i add this `google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.HINDI` in options array in destination language .it works fine.but using variable c at the same time gives `Uncaught Error: Exception in Controller: Unsupported language [object Object] in targetLangCode array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you have asked a separate question now. Originally, your issue was regarding how to access the properties of the [LanguageCode enum](https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/reference#LanguageCode)

Your new question is **"Now that I can do that, how do I dynamically change the destination language of the transliterated control?"**

Your approach of removing and re-adding the textarea will work but it is not necessary.

Transliterate offers a method for this: [`.setLanguagePair(sourceLanguage, destinationLanguage)`](https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/reference#methods)

A more performant approach would be to `transliterate` the element on load and then change the language dynamically with the user's selection like this:

```
var options = {
  shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
  transliterationEnabled: true,
  sourceLanguage: 'en',
  destinationLanguage: ['or'],// set it to anything to start, it wont be visible anyway
};
var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);
 control.makeTransliteratable(['message']);

$("#langpair").change(function() {
  $('#message').css('display','block');
  var data = this.value;
  $("#language_name").text(data);
  var destinationLanguage = google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode[data];
  control.setLanguagePair('en', destinationLanguage);
});
```

#### [See this updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxByQP)

---

**Answer to your original question**

To access an object property using a string held in a variable, you can use the object key syntax instead of dot notation.

Change your code to:

```
var c = [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode[data]];
```

Note that `var a` and `var b` are no longer needed

Comment: Buddy you are a rockstar.i dont have enough repu. to upvote.

Comment: One small issue it works only for the first time selecting language but when i again select anything it does nothing.

Comment: selecting language second time mixes first language and second in textarea when new words are added and sentence becomes `ही ስጃቁን ሆው አረ यू `. First and last words are HINDI and middle part is AMHARIC.

Comment: Do you have this working online somewhere I can see it? It's hard to debug that part without being able to see it happen

Comment: can we move dis discussion to chat ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Still m having trouble in events like using space key after every word and copy pasting text directly into text area.if you can help with this.Thanks

Comment: select English from dropdown.it will start converting to someother language.

Comment: Sorry, english should not be an option in the list, I meant to remove that. `Transliterate`  will not accept the same language for both in and out, instead, it will throw the following exception: `Exception in setLanguagePair: Unsupported sourceLanguage & targetLanguage pair: sourceLanguage: en targetLanguage: en` and will not change the language so what you are seeing is the default language I set of `'or'`, just remove the english option from the dropdown

Comment: About the other part, when you say " like using space key after every word", what do you mean by that exactly? Do you want it to NOT  translate the text when you hit space?

Comment: if i add a single word in textarea manually and proceed to next input without pressing space key.Text will not change.This is an issue.Another one is when i paste text in textarea and do the same.text remains in original language.

Comment: Keyup works in this. but not copy paste -http://www.vishalon.net/PramukhIME/JavaScriptLibrary.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Bugfixer but thats not really the route we're on here

Comment: Please check accepted answer in question.i want such event http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042193/how-to-trigger-an-event-in-input-text-after-i-stop-typing-writing

Comment: @James will each textarea only ever have one translated language in it, or can the user have several language in one then go the the next one and so on?

Comment: sir please don't leave your other important work for this.

Comment: first user select language from dropdown and then paste the sms template.no change event is fired in dis case.text remains same.There is only one textarea.all language will be in same textarea.

Comment: @James Hmm. thats tougher than it should be, sending keypress events manually doesnt trigger the transliteration. Ill have to come back to this when I have a bit more time

Answer (score 1):

I recreated textarea when dropdown is selected.it is working fine now.May be this code will help others.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    google.load("elements", "1", {
        packages: "transliteration"
    });
</script>    
<span id="language_name"></span>
<select name="langpair" style="height:32px; padding:0;" id="langpair" size="1">
    <option value="ENGLISH">ENGLISH</option>
    <option value="AMHARIC" >AMHARIC</option>
    <option value="HINDI">HINDI</option>
</select>
<br/>
<hr>
<span id="language_area"></span>
<br/>
<script>
    $("#langpair").change(function() {
        var end = this.value;
        //document.getElementById("message").value = "";
        $("#language_area").html("");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            data: {data: end},
            url: "changelanguage.php",
            success: function(data)
            {
                $("#language_area").html('<textarea class="form-control" maxlength="160" id="message" name="message" rows="3" placeholder="Message"></textarea>');
                $("#language_name").html(data);
                var options = {
                    sourceLanguage: google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
                    destinationLanguage: [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode[data]],
                    shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
                    transliterationEnabled: true
                };

                //console.log(options);

                var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);
                control.makeTransliteratable(['message']);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here id the [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEbgpX).But it doesn't works without pressing space after every word as well as on pasting text.

Comment: Sorry I had to step away for a bit, please see the update to my answer above.