# Call apex class method immediate after input text

Tags: function, events, autocomplete, apex

I have below code where after I do enter an auto complete input text value I need to click elsewhere for the apex class method `{!applyfiler}` to work. But I need to call that method instantly after input text value entered without any further click. Can someone please help me here with javascript any if possible?

**Apex Page code**

```
<apex:pageblockSectionItem > 
     <apex:outputText rendered="{!userType == 'Admin' || userType == 'HomeOffice' || userType == 'Field'}">
          Compliance Incident Transaction Name
     </apex:outputText>
     <apex:inputText styleClass="apexCITautocomplete" value="{!selectedCIT}" id="Rep">
          <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!applyfiler}" rerender="pb"/>
     </apex:inputtext> 
</apex:pageblockSectionItem>
```

Comment: What do you mean by auto complete. Will this text field populate on page load itself?

Comment: are you looking something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042193/how-to-trigger-an-event-in-input-text-after-i-stop-typing-writing