# Retrieving data while user is typing

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

I have five text fields in my page and when the user types something in first textfield, I need to retrieve the values based on the first textfield. Right now, I have hardcode the value as 121, which is returning the value properly from DB, but how do I make it dynamic ?

```
<?php echo $form->textField(emp::model()->findByAttributes(array('id' => '121' )),'empno');  ?>
```

Comment: javascript-> AJAX

Comment: Use jquery and ajax.

Comment: Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042193/how-to-trigger-an-event-in-input-text-after-i-stop-typing-writing

Comment: are you using yii 1.1 or yii2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ajax call for it while typing in the textbox as follows:

```
$("textbox").on('keyup',function(){

    // use get or post request here to retrieve the data
    $.post('url',{parameters},function(data){
        //code to set the data in you UI
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Yii's builtin autocomplete widget for that. It's based on jQuery UI library.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiAutoComplete

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete',array(
    'name'=>'city',
    'sourceUrl'=> "<your keyword suggestion url here>",
    // additional javascript options for the autocomplete plugin
    'options'=>array(
        'minLength'=>'2',
    ),
));
```