# Form validation using Jquery plugin and additional methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I want to use the jquery plugin for validating my form with letters only in name section. such that when a user enters special characters or numbers it gives an error. Also i want to check the form validation as the users types the information i.e. realtime validation before submitting the form.

```js
//jquery validation
 
 // Wait for the DOM to be ready
$(function() {
  // Initialize form validation on the registration form.
  // It has the name attribute "registration"
  $("form[name='book']").validate({
    // Specify validation rules
    rules: {
      // The key name on the left side is the name attribute
      // of an input field. Validation rules are defined
      // on the right side
      fname: {
        required: true,
        lettersonly: true
        },
      lname:{
        required: true,
        lettersonly: true
        },
      email: {
        required: true,
        // Specify that email should be validated
        // by the built-in "email" rule
        email: true
      },
     
    // Specify validation error messages
    messages: {
      fname: {
      required:"Please enter your firstname",
      lettersonly:"Letters allowed only"
      },
      lname: {
      required:"Please enter your firstname",
      lettersonly:"Letters allowed only"
      },
     
      email: "Please enter a valid email address"
    },
    // Make sure the form is submitted to the destination defined
    // in the "action" attribute of the form when valid
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="design/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="design/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/additional-methods.js"></script>

<form name="book" id="book" action="" method="post">

    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
            <label class="" for="fname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="" for="lname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
            <label class="" for="date">Date</label>
            <input type="text" id="date" class="form-control datepicker px-2" placeholder="Date of visit">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="" for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="" for="treatment">Service You Want</label>
            <select name="treatment" id="treatment" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Hair Cut</option>
                <option value="">Hair Coloring</option>
                <option value="">Perms and Curls</option>
                <option value="">Hair Conditioning</option>
                <option value="">Manicure</option>
                <option value="">Pedicure</option>
                <option value="">Nails Extension</option>
                <option value="">Nail Design</option>
                <option value="">Waxing Eyebrows</option>
                <option value="">Waxing Hands/Legs</option>
                <option value="">Full Face Waxing</option>
                <option value="">Full Body/Body Parts Wax</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="" for="note">Notes</label>
            <textarea name="note" id="note" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Write your notes or questions here..."></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <center><input type="submit" value="Book Now" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"></center>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

I want to use the jquery plugin for validating my form with letters only in name section. such that when a user enters special characters or numbers it gives an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//jquery validation booking page
 
 // Wait for the DOM to be ready
$(function() {
  // Initialize form validation on the registration form.
  // It has the name attribute "registration"
  $("form[name='book']").validate({
   //on key up validation
   onkeyup: function(element) {
      $(element).valid(); 
    },  
    // Specify validation rules
    rules: {
      // The key name on the left side is the name attribute
      // of an input field. Validation rules are defined
      // on the right side
      fname: {
        required: true,
        lettersonly: true
        },
      lname:{
        required: true,
        lettersonly: true
        },
      email: {
        required: true,
        // Specify that email should be validated
        // by the built-in "email" rule
        email: true
      },
      password: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
      }
    },
    // Specify validation error messages
    messages: {
      fname: {
      required:"Please enter your firstname",
      lettersonly:"Letters allowed only"
      },
      lname: {
      required:"Please enter your lastname",
      lettersonly:"Letters allowed only"
      },
      email: "Please enter a valid email address"
    },
    // Make sure the form is submitted to the destination defined
    // in the "action" attribute of the form when valid
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thisis the complete running JS code. Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

`````
      var RegEx = /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/; 

      if (RegEx.test($('#input').val())) {

      } 
      else {
          $('#input').val("");
      }
});​````

You have to wrap all the input elements in <form></form> and use jquery Validate plugin. Refer this link: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/ for detailed explanation
`````

Answer (score 0):

How about doing something like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

  <form id="form">
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <div id="error"></div>
  </form>

<script>
;(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        donetyping: function(callback,timeout){
            timeout = timeout || 1e3; // 1 second default timeout
            var timeoutReference,
                doneTyping = function(el){
                    if (!timeoutReference) return;
                    timeoutReference = null;
                    callback.call(el);
                };
            return this.each(function(i,el){
                var $el = $(el);
                // Chrome Fix (Use keyup over keypress to detect backspace)
                // thank you @palerdot
                $el.is(':input') && $el.on('keyup keypress paste',function(e){
                    // This catches the backspace button in chrome, but also prevents
                    // the event from triggering too preemptively. Without this line,
                    // using tab/shift+tab will make the focused element fire the callback.
                    if (e.type=='keyup' && e.keyCode!=8) return;

                    // Check if timeout has been set. If it has, "reset" the clock and
                    // start over again.
                    if (timeoutReference) clearTimeout(timeoutReference);
                    timeoutReference = setTimeout(function(){
                        // if we made it here, our timeout has elapsed. Fire the
                        // callback
                        doneTyping(el);
                    }, timeout);
                }).on('blur',function(){
                    // If we can, fire the event since we're leaving the field
                    doneTyping(el);
                });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

function validate(value) {
  var regex = /\d/g;
  if (regex.test(value)) {
    $('#error').text('Only text allowed!');
  } else {
    $('#error').empty();
  }
}

$('input[name=name]').donetyping(function(e){
  validate($(this).val());
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Credits to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14042239/9379378

Comment: Thanks for the solution but i found a solution via the additional-methods.js file

Comment: $("form[name='book']").validate({
   //on key up validation
   onkeyup: function(element) {
      $(element).valid(); 
    },